# What, exactly, is Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I read the tour page on Documentation and it looks to me like it is meant to document errors and such things. That seems broad to me. Could anyone explain exactly what it is and how it's going to be used?

Comment: The million dollar question...that everyone fears to answer.

Comment: Have you read the [announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/)? The long answer is, Documentation is what the community makes with it. We are working on providing a framework and have some ideas about how it'll go, but ultimately it'll be up to contributors to shape it.

Comment: A similar question was on my mind, but surely one can learn more than "*document errors and such things*" from the Tour page?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329486/ and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329291/

Comment: I also have no idea what it is. Am I supposed to be going to people's answers and click some button to add a documentation section for the classes that are in their answer?

Comment: @JonEricson: "*Documentation is what the community makes with it.*" But the community does not have the power to control the structure of documentation. We can only fill in the blanks in a form letter; the form of that letter is defined by you. So it's entirely reasonable to ask what those blanks mean.

Comment: Related: [Trying to understand Stack Overflow Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329691)

Comment: It's a new toy that has *"some assembly required"* but there were no assembly instructions or pictures in the box. Hundreds of people try piecing it together, each with their own vision of what it should look like.

Comment: In short, it's crap !

Comment: @charlietfl ... and fighting with each other when they assembled it The Wrong Way™.

Comment: @JonEricson - It sounds like really ridiculous.  It's like saying: we have created an online word editor and have some ideas about a plot, but ultimately it's up to you to write a book.  You will be doing it altogether, having no idea what others are doing, stepping on each other toes but at the end it will all work out.

Comment: stackoverflow people say Documentation is here to stay, and there are *partners* (other companies/projects) involved in the Documentation thing (probably why they insist it's here to stay). I think somebody(s) at SO have something in mind for what Documentation is supposed to be. Funny that the people actually writing the documentation seem to be the last let in on the secret.

Comment: [This is documentation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exquisite_corpse)

Comment: good question..

Comment: doesn't give me any reputation! I wouldn't use that...

Comment: Joel on what Documentation should be: http://avc.com/2016/07/stack-documentation/

Answer (score 74):

### ["Official answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation)

This is "the official version" of what Documentation is:

> Documentation is broad, and it is a general reference. You aren't documenting a specific problem you're facing, you're helping others deal with an entire class of problems by documenting.
>
> These resources haven't had a place on Stack Overflow, Documentation
> gives them a home.
>
> It's all about examples.
>
> Examples, examples, examples - show beats tell. In Stack Overflow Documentation, examples are the star of the show. Anyone can add one, so good topics will eventually have several useful examples. And much like answers on Stack Overflow, the most helpful ones will usually be voted up to be right on top

[Read more](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/)

---

### What it is right now

It's really [hard to tell what it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329461/2002588), or what it isn't, but I can tell what I think it is right now:

- The perfect way to [get easy reputation by making almost no contributions at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329513/2002588).
- A place to find a lot of code snippets, some of them brilliant, [some of they completely wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328978/minimum-tag-score-for-adding-documentation).
- A magical place where if you go into a page, and go back the next day it might be completely different because making edits on it is extremely easy for everybody.
- The place where people who put effort in creating good documentation go to bang their head on their desk because an example got vandalized after they rejected 20 awful edits on it and now they have to roll it back, for the 5th time.

---

### What it could be, after *a lot* of work on it

A documentation system oriented for programming with peer review where everybody with an internet connection in the world can learn and contribute, updated constantly with a reputation system that rewards valuable community members who put their effort into making it work.

Which potentially could be extended to many other areas such as science, and be transformed slowly into the "knowledge base of humanity" (a.k.a. Wikipedia with reputation).

Comment: Dilemma: I'd really like easy access to the 10,000-rep moderator privileges (!!!), but when I actually tried Documentation during the closed beta, it just didn't seem interesting or worthwhile, and I just can't quite bring myself to spend time there again. What to do, what to do....

Comment: First though "Oh god, not another rant" … then burst out laughing … "magical place", "bang their head on their desk", "20" (!!), "5th time" … Thanks for ranting with humor at least :-)

Comment: @bwoebi I've been trough that myself, I rather take it with humor than getting mad :)

Comment: ++ it really does have the potential to be amazing, but I swear if I have to reject one more Entity Framework topic request from the C# language, I'm going to scream.

Comment: @RubberDuck your kind screams now? I was living a lie...

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo - you hit right at the target :)

Comment: I confess I didn't actually read your answer before writing mine. Partially, I expected a rant and partially I didn't want to be writing in a reactionary way. But I needn't have worried. This is a fine (and concise) answer. Thank you.

Comment: "Wikipedia with reputation" - man, I'm glad Wikipedia doesn't have a rep system.

Answer (score 11):

We've tried to explain Stack Overflow Documentation in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation), the [blog post announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/) and the [meta announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta). If after reading all that you are *still unsure* about what the feature is for, let me try another approach: long, wandering personal anecdote.

For [two thousand years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_encyclopedias) encyclopedias were outrageously expensive. The only people who could read them were either extremely rich or in the business of copying books. As technology advanced, the price of reproducing books dropped and more people were able to get their hands on compiled volumes of knowledge. By my grandparent's generation, encyclopedias were sold door-to-door as subscription service (starting with Volume 1: "Aalto—Arithmetic"). Competition and technology drove down the price to the point my parents bought me an entire set (World Book (used), if I recall correctly) when I was in junior high. The year after I graduated high school, Microsoft released [an encyclopedia on CD-ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encarta), which opened the doors to even more people. Including the cost of the PC, even that was out of the reach of many, however.

Then Wikipedia (plus Google) changed Encyclopedias forever. Not only has the cost dropped to essentially free for readers, the **barrier for entry to contribute evaporated**. Instead of hiring top experts in the topic, as traditional encyclopedias do, Wikipedia remains [largely open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia#Openness) for anyone to contribute to, which seems like a dubious idea. However, [as Joel put it](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/28.html):

> The early criticism of Wikipedia: “I went to this article and it was wrong.” By the time you read the criticism, the article has been fixed. There was that year, not last year, but the year before, when every traditional journalist wrote a funny thought piece in their newspaper about something they looked up in Wikipedia and just how wrong it was. By the time their column appeared in print, the Wikipedia article was corrected, making a liar out of the journalist. Eventually they learned to stop writing that story.

So to steal my own thunder, Joel said that stuff about Wikipedia in order to describe Q&A. By any reasonable measure, Stack Overflow did to programming questions what Wikipedia did to encyclopedias. And by "Stack Overflow", I don't just mean the model which [can be cloned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones), but the community of programmers of all abilities who have donated time and effort to create something useful. We try our level best to make the system run smoothly, but the magic is really in *you*, the people who write and curate the content.

Computer manuals followed the evolution of encyclopedias at a much greater pace. When I was a working programmer, we had tons of printed manuals scattered across our desks and taking up shelf space. A few years ago, there was a massive office shakeup and people were forced to move their stuff from one cubicle to another. (To be clear, this was [not Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/why-we-still-believe-in-private-offices/).) Printed manuals found their way into piles in the breakroom with "free!" sticky-notes. I grabbed a few out of nostalgia, but most of them ended up in the recycling because the information is all online now anyway.

Most technical Documentation is in the "Encarta online" stage of evolution. Ages ago, I bought [*The Perl CD Bookshelf*](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/pr/861), which, as the name suggests, was a collection of Perl books on CD. Since the content was formatted as HTML, the CD included a little web server so that you could read in your browser. As strange as it sounds, that was revolutionary at the time. Unfortunately, the revolution stalled. If you look at Perl's official documentation, which includes many [well-written articles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html), it's not too dissimilar from pages served off a CD. Being an open source project, there is at least a way to update Perl's documentation, but it's not as easy as editing Wikipedia.

Ok. So we want to do to Documentation what we did to Q&A and what Wikipedia did to encyclopedias, right? Not so fast, cowpoke. Both the encyclopedia and programmer question landscapes were dysfunctional when they were replaced. Stack Overflow launched to replace [the hyphen site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12989/1438) and a disparate collection of mailing lists and newsgroups. Like many other programmers, I leapt into the stream like a [grizzly during spawning season](https://www.nps.gov/yell/learn/nature/beartrout.htm). The system didn't start off perfect, but it was *far better* than anything else that existed.

To be honest, there is a lot of excellent documentation out there. [Emacs has a wiki](https://emacswiki.org/) that can be edited Wikipedia-style and is of high quality. When I run across a problem using Emacs, I often prefer the wiki over the official documentation because it tends to have fresher information. And if you already are comfortable with existing documentation, I'm not sure there's any reason to switch. Plus, it's a [waste to duplicate effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328807/1438) when there's no pressing need. Therefore, Stack Overflow Documentation needs to offer something new.

What we hit on was that **most technical documentation lacks sufficient emphasis on examples**. A number of people we've talked to have had an experience something like mine but with different technologies:

1. I need to write a query for research I'm doing with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I forgot how do something in SQL or maybe don't know if it's even possible.
2. Google gives me a link to the official documentation, which I click on out of a sense of duty. After several minutes scanning the manual, I give up and scroll to the examples at the bottom of the page.
3. I hit the back button, find the Stack Overflow link, use the sidebar links to jump from the MySQL version to the SQL Server answer, and use the top answer as a starting point.

The problem with step #2 isn't that the official documentation is *bad* (or at least that's not the primary problem). Rather, the manual is written from the perspective of *someone developing SQL Server* and not from a user's perspective. (Meta comment: that's at least part of the reason the resources I linked to in the first paragraph might not work for you.) I don't need to know all the theory of how the feature works or the edge cases or the optional parameters or any of the things it might be important to document. I just need a little reminder of where to start. Even if the question turns out to be nothing like the problem I'm trying to solve, having a bit of working code helps me to move forward.

So, while we'd like to revolutionize Documentation, we're starting off with a humbler goal. When programmers need a snippet of code to demonstrate some language feature, they can search Google, click a Stack Overflow link, and get that code without the distractions of questions, comments or any of the cruft a the top of most online documentation. We are betting the feature on the proposition that **programmers will appreciate easy access to good examples**.

Now there are a lot of other features we've thrown into the mix because they are things we wish documentation did better as a rule or so that Documentation fits into the Stack Overflow ecosystem. But if you could do only one thing, we'd like you to consider contributing, reviewing and honing examples. Obviously there are other ways to get involved, but the core of the feature is **examples by and for programmers**.

Comment: It might have been better to call it **Examples** instead of **Documentation**.

Comment: This is exactly how I expect to see SO docs, but.... then when i open a tag i'm instead seeing official docs being replicated. not copy pasted/plagiarized, but duplicated none the less.

Comment: @hatchet: I don't disagree with you. The name was certainly the subject (many) intense internal debates. In the end we decided to be a little bit ambitious. It's possible to imagine a future where new projects start off building example-based documentation right on Stack Overflow as the feature matures and it would be a shame to cut that evolutionary path off prematurely.

Comment: @JonEricson - given that *Documentation* is rather open-ended, I think it would be really helpful if SO picked a little topic, and did a kick-ass coverage of that topic that shows all you hope this will be. Then we can use that as a model to spread goodness and light. Let's not start with bad and try to evolve that to ok. Let's start with good and evolve that to great.

Comment: @KevinB: This is our fault. Between the messaging (which is perhaps unclear) and missing limits and the lack of editorial features and the unexpected enthusiasm of users (both veteran and new to Stack Overflow), there's a lot of content that's in the example section but isn't really an example. We [are working](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329557/1438) to correct those mistakes as I speak.

Comment: @hatchet: We did [a little of that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329590/1438), but it's not well publicized. However, the bigger issue is that we really don't want to tell you what to do. As crazy as the public beta has been so far, it's teaching us [what the feature still lacks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329575/chaos-building-in-sql-section-of-documentation#comment374948_329575). We don't want to dictate how the community ought to work (even if we could). Instead we want to see your crazy ideas and build features to support what turns out to work well.

Comment: @JonEricson: "*the bigger issue is that we really don't want to tell you what to do.*" The problem with that is that you *are* telling us what to do. You've called it "documentation". You associate documentation with "tags". Each tag has a number of "topics". And each topic has a number of "examples". These words give people ideas about what *should* be where. And it gives people different ideas. And in most cases, those ideas are *different* for different people. You're telling us to build whatever we want, but only within this very inflexible structure.

Comment: It's frustrating. I want to help clean it up, add quality content, etc, but when i go to clean it up, i feel like a jerk because i'm deleting a lot of content contributed by other users that simply saw the documentation as something I did not. But by not defining what it IS supposed to be, maybe I am being a jerk and shouldn't be trying to enforce what I see docs as being, because it isn't defined. (but now it kinda is, i guess?)

Comment: @KevinB: [You are not alone.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329575/chaos-building-in-sql-section-of-documentation#comment374948_329575) But this is the reason we have the beta label. One thing that might be reassuring is that you can always get a link to deleted content. (See the "No more broken links" item in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation).)

Comment: @NicolBolas: We've written a lot of words about those sections, but it seems people are fixed on one: "Documentation". It's waaaay too late to correct that misperception, but it's not at all too late to create the sorts of examples you wish you'd found the last time you forgot a language feature.

Comment: After the chat ban by SE employees and tone of other posts I read which felt like SE was saying "We've explained it enough - you're just not reading it or its your fault for not getting it". I expected another post of the same tone just pointing to the tour and update that I have already read. Instead, this finally explains the scope and goal of SOD plainly. I'm still not convinced this is a good direction for SO but this at least convinces me to give it, and SE employees, some time to see if (a big *if*) SO can **improve the UI**, rep, and other problems.

Comment: I pushed super hard for the name Examples from the first time I heard about this proposal. Couldn't a highly curated group of Q&A around some extremely narrow thing be bundled together into a form of examples?

Comment: "Documentation" gives off a very strong vibe that we should not only be providing examples but lots of prose to explain how everything works - even if you tell me not to do that I'm still going to be inclined to do it because I'm writing "documentation."

Comment: so, documentation is intended to answer the question [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) :)

Comment: "Even if the question turns out to be nothing like the problem I'm trying to solve, having a bit of working code helps me to move forward." But isn't this Q&A again, not Documentation? Also there you have bits of working code. Also "... the core of the feature is examples by and for programmers." sounds a bit like a slightly different Q&A, say a Q&E.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: That's certainly one way to go. In fact, I was pretty sure that's where y'all were going with [this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Not sure why that didn't go anywhere further, but it seems like no real work has gone into encouraging collaboration. It's early yet, but Documentation has seen lot's of people working on refining content in ways that we rarely see on Q&A.

Comment: @AntP: I could have gone on for a few more paragraphs about how frustrating programming manuals remain. If you want to write lots of prose to fix problems in official documentation, feel free. That's why Examples allow prose and why we have Remarks. I'm not saying that other bits of Documentation aren't important. Instead, we are emphasising examples because they are particularly lacking in our survey.

Comment: @Trilarion: Answers clearly need a question to go with. But examples? Not so much. So imagine taking answers to overly broad questions, editing them into a more generally readable state, removing cruft, and posting them elsewhere. (Given all answers here are CC BY-SA, that's something anyone can do already, by the way.) Documentation is just such a place.

Comment: "We've tried to explain Stack Overflow Documentation in the tour, the blog post announcement and the meta announcement. If after reading all that you are still unsure about what the feature is for..." yes, we are. Because nothing there explains what it is. It's a bunch of marketing nonsense that contradicts itself. See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330289/what-is-the-purpose-of-stackoverflow-documentation

Comment: "@hatchet: I don't disagree with you. The name was certainly the subject (many) intense internal debates. In the end we decided to be a little bit ambitious. It's possible to imagine a future where new projects start off building example-based documentation right on Stack Overflow as the feature matures and it would be a shame to cut that evolutionary path off prematurely." ---- this is why the iPod wasn't called the iPhone. Try again on the naming thunking. Admit you got it wrong, that it's causing massive confusion, and rewind... it's just a beta, after all...

Comment: After reading commentary from people that run the show, I think there's an enormous arrogance in play. It seems the powers that be think it's ok to redefine the meaning of a heavily used word (like "Documentation") and attempt to make it mean anything they think or desire it to mean, even if that's causing maximum confusion and disorientation for others. Ironically, generally speaking, this is the biggest problem with documentation in programming, that it's usually written in such a way that only those that already understand it can grasp it. Think of the audience instead of yourselves.