# Who is the target audience for documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I am a semi-frequent contributor to the C++ Language documentation section. I am currently dissatisfied with the ["Hello World" example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/206/getting-started-with-c-language/774/hello-world#t=201705100040452736613).

As of the time of writing, it is over 600 words and contains many technical terms that nobody outside of C++ would understand. So a beginner that just begins to read the "Hello World" example section (because "Hello World" is traditionally the point-of-contact for many beginners in tutorials) is simply going to be lost.

To my knowledge, there is no canonical guide for writing for Stack Overflow Documentation (SOD). But the question I want to bring up is: **"Who is our target audience?"** SOD examples will look wildly differently if writing for beginners vs. novices vs. working experts vs. academic programmers.

Stack Overflow has had a history of catering to "experts" but Documentation may not necessarily fall into the same vein since tutorial-style topics are currently accepted. What then, is our focus?

Comment: This is a good question that I'll be answering with my view soon. But don't think our target is _absolute_ beginners. There tend to be lots of resources for that level. I don't think the C++ Hello World example is _too_ obtuse for those who have some experience. (Though it would probably help to have a few more links for the bolded terminology.)

Comment: @JonEricson: "*But don't think our target is absolute beginners.*" Hello, World is only useful for absolute beginners. So you're saying that we shouldn't have those kinds of examples at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think K&R's first chapter has it right. The important thing isn't the actual program written, but the steps it takes to get it to compile and run. Having learned many new languages over the years, I appreciate these simple programs that make sure your environment is ready for development. But I don't need that first program's writeup to talk down to me. If you gotta write about "scope resolution operators" just say that. Don't try to sugarcoat or hide necessary complexity.

Comment: @JonEricson: "*The important thing isn't the actual program written, but the steps it takes to get it to compile and run.*" I agree. But that example contains *absolutely nothing* about compiling or running the program. It does what most Hello, World tutorials do: explain the behavior of the actual code, not making sure that your build environment works. So even if Hello, World examples are not a bad idea, this one most certainly isn't getting the job done.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Ah. But the question is whether the presentation of the program is _too sophisticated_ and cutting out brand new users. In any case, it seems the C++ folks have split [Compiling and Building](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4708/compiling-and-building#t=201705100432571808606) into it's own topic. Perhaps the pinned example should be edited to include a link?

Comment: @JonEricson Of course. But that's not the issue here -- the question is how should we tailor our writing to our perceived audience, and who is our perceived audience? SO doesn't seem to have made it clear who is the target that documentation is targeting. It's too touchy-feely so I feel unsure of how basic of a style I need to write in.

Comment: If we are writing towards an expert-audience, can we indicate as such? Or should we try to do a lowest common denominator-like writing style to catch even the first-time beginners?

Comment: That's funny, because I remember reading somewhere that absolute beginners were just as explicitly encouraged to contribute as experts.

Comment: Everybody wants to join a successful post. This is a problem regardless of the target audience. I agree the example is bad, and worse, to me it validates negative C++ stereotypes: *"Print Hello World! Oh, and this is a preprocessor directive!"* ... *"And you can also do it this way, but don't - it's bad!"*

Comment: SOD was a good Idea, but instead of covering the basics of a language (which a documentation is normally meant for) people try to get all their knowledge and opinions about programming into the posts

Comment: @I4mpi [Docs is in fact indexed by Google (which is the only search engine that actually matters).](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+hello+world+site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation) And no, the *concept* of Docs isn't doomed to fail - we just didn't implement it properly.

Comment: @dorukayhan Thanks for the correction, seems like it does get indexed. Although it still doesn't seem to be easily discoverable as its page rank seems to be low, if you remove the "site:" from the query then SO.docs isn't on the first 3 result pages (even if you add "docs" or "documentation"). Also, I never said that Docs is doomed to fail, just that it's  a useless heap of crap in its current state. And given that the responses from SE to the criticism on meta were not very encouraging, I don't think this will change anytime soon.

Comment: (I started writing an answer but couldn't find good examples). To my understanding: **Each topic has its own target audience.** Introductory topics should be simple and accessible to beginners. Advanced topics should make reasonable assumptions that the target audience understand basic concepts.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think you are equivocating. Doc is intended (among other things) to be a easier way for people who are new to Stack Overflow to contribute. There are plenty of excellent programmers who have no interest in asking or answering questions. Our user research suggests the site is intimidating for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @JonEricson "I think K&R's first chapter has it right". FYI the first chapter of K&R 2nd edition is of about as low quality as the rest of the book. The famous "hello world" example will not work properly under any version of the C standard. Which you can read more about on [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/getting-started-with-c-language/3675/original-hello-world-in-kr-c#t=20170511133844384464) :). K&R overall embraces the spirit of "lets make confident statements where we demonstrate and teach really bad programming practice". Not exactly a good role model.

Comment: as a newbie to C++ but a programmer i found a lack of empathy and a " say a lot and try to impress" syndrom.

Comment: @TraffyT: I hadn't thought about the tone of the example. I can certainly see how it might be off-putting. I've seen similar things with other topics. I wonder if we ought to borrow from [Wikipedia's guidance about tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Writing_better_articles#Tone)?

Comment: @Lundin: I think the key phrase is "2nd edition". (I used the first edition and it had a bigger problem as I recall: it didn't include stdio.h!) Clearly we can do a lot better than  a printed book for the [same reason WIkipedia is better than a volume of encyclopedias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330003/1438). Thanks for pointing me to the example.

Comment: @JonEricson The 1st edition is mostly an ancient tome from the dark ages before any form of standardization existed. The 2nd edition is a failed attempt to adapt the ancient tome to ISO C - the authors either didn't have enough knowledge of the standardized language or they did a sloppy work converting it. In either case, the 2nd edition should have been avoided back then, and it should be avoided even more so after the year 1999.

Comment: The target audience is anyone who is _so_ incapable of using real, formal, official, properly constructed and authoritatively maintained documentation that they are comfortable resorting to this mess instead!

Comment: @BoltClock That is cringe-inducing

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion there has been way too much focus on creating and considering singular examples in Documentation.

Instead, the content should be focused on topics. There is no need to make a 30,000 character example ever. It would be of much more use to have several topics with several examples that cover the same material. This is, of course, a lot harder to accomplish in that most users do not have the time to sit down and write a topic with a set of examples all at once. However, that would be a far more productive use of the format.

Using a more granular approach to topics would allow for any target audience. It would also mean that there would seemingly be more duplication. That is a requirement though. Why should there be only one example that explains Arrays in Java? The easy answer is that there shouldn't be, and no one example should hold carte blanche over that entire subject.

The main obstacle to this type of content coverage is the current use of the tagging system. Tags limit the scope of topics, and as a result limit the usefulness of Documentation as a whole.

If the content in Documentation was instead tied to tag sets, by topic, then it would have many benefits. Which is to say, you create a topic, and then tag it with the set of tags applicable. This would

- drive more contribution as more granular audiences, examples and topics would be available
- allow more freedom to label content, as titles could be more descriptive of the expected content than simply "Arrays" or "Async"
- improve search by allowing more granular keywords as well as fitting in with the already existing elasticsearch design SO uses

Comment: I'm starting to come around to the viewpoint that singleton tags is limiting the number of topics. It's also making reuse harder. Why does every language tag have a Regular Expressions topic? It's a mess and there are no good solutions without loosening up the structure a bit.

Comment: In my opinion, not all knowledge is topical-hierarchical. If regular expression cross-cuts across many languages, how should we handle the distribution of information? SOD gives no guidance on this topic. Besides, why shouldn't there be a regular expression for each language? Perl regex vs. other regex isy different.

Answer (score 10):

I think the best audience target is somewhere along the spectrum:

- an especially gifted and motivated new-to-programming student to
- a seasoned professional developer who sometimes forgets how things work.

I learned C as a summer intern using nothing but a large codebase (that I needed to modify for my project) and a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie's *The C Programming Language*. At a spare 189 pages plus a reference manual, this volume did not hold my hand. It wasn't easy to learn that way, but it was possible. Meanwhile, it still teaches me something new every time I reread a chapter. That's great documentation.

You might think that sort of documentation is impossible with many authors. But I have a similar experience learning thing via Wikipedia. I'll read an article to learn a concept and then, once I know how to apply it, come back for a bit more nuance and detail. While you need to know a little physics or history or biology or mathematics to get started, there's usually enough detail and references to give readers a pretty comprehensive understanding of topics. And once I know a topic inside and out, it helps to go back to Wikipedia to remind myself of these details.

To be clear, Stack Overflow Documentation is not really at that level yet. It's very inconsistent and, unlike Wikipedia, difficult to browse. I've tried to use our Documentation to learn new languages and the problem I've had isn't that the concepts are too difficult, but rather the range of topics are too narrow and hard to discover. (I'm writing an announcement to lay out the next steps in that direction. Stay tuned!) But the goal is for Documentation to be useful long after people have absorbed the concepts.

I read over [our Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/206/getting-started-with-c-language/774/hello-world#t=201705100040452736613) and did [a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world+c%2B%2B) to see what is out there already. It looks like line-by-line explanations are not unusual. But it does seem like this version includes some hard-won advice such as:

> One could also add `using namespace std;` underneath `#include <iostream>`, removing the need to type `std::` in front of identifiers that belong to the `std` namespace.
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> int main()
> {
>     cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
> }
> ```
>
> However, [doing so is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

My C++ is pretty out-of-date as I never had namespaces. So I personally appreciate that paragraph. I don't think it hurts the example's utility as an introduction for people who have no C++ experience. I'd probably be helpful to include a prominent link to [Compiling and Building](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4708/compiling-and-building#t=201705100432571808606), however. In fact, one of the things that makes Wikipedia so useful to so many people is that every article links to many other resources (both internal and external).

Ultimately, I think contributors to Documentation should **write what they themselves would be interested in reading**. It's surprisingly hard to write for an imagined audience. Writing for yourself turns out to be a lot easier. And if Documentation works out anything like Q&A, you might end up being in the target audience too.

Comment: "*I don't think it hurts the example's utility as an introduction for people who have no C++ experience.*" As someone who has written learning materials for new users, I do believe this hurts the example's utility to them. Introductory material works best when it is *focused* on explaining a single thing, with no distractions. Linking to that bad practice page creates confusion by introducing a *very* complicated series of C++ topics to people unprepared for it. Good learning materials are focused on teaching one thing at a time and teaching it well. Misplaced good advice is still *misplaced*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You might be right. I recently listened to [this talk](https://www.heavybit.com/library/video/how-great-documentation-drives-developer-adoption/) and was struck by Question 6 where the speaker descibed watching new users learn from his documentation. One of our next steps is going to be testing documentation on people without specific experience in the technology.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It also occurs to me that an example along the lines of "Hello World for the non-programmer" would be interesting to try out.

Comment: @JonEricson But that's the thing. If we want to write for two separate audiences, there is no good way to indicate as so since the system doesn't differentiate between people. It's an unwritten audience-choosing decision that new people will not understand unless it's written somewhere and clear for people to see.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: We are considering different paths or levels for different users. This came up over and over in our user testing. If we do something like that, the audience will be self-selecting. That said, nobody is new more than once. It's hard to write continuously useful documentation for extremely new users that's also relevant to other folks. In my opinion, aiming a little bit higher on the experience spectrum will pay off. (For the moment, I really think writing another Hello World with a "This is for non-programmers" title would be a worthwhile exercise.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour clearly says on the first line "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." As such, explaining hello world to non-programmers is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: If I was to bitch about this sample, the not returning anything from main exception to the entire language seems like trivia that belongs in a "how to make your code unreadable" topic and not in a "Hello World" topic. Sure, I was curious why that's allowed where as renaming it from `main` to `test` generates an error. Showing that as the first example though seems a very poor introduction to the language and arguably promotes bad and inconsistant coding practices.

Answer (score 9):

You say that it contains "many technical terms that nobody outside of C++ would understand", but that is precisely the point. It is impossible to understand C++ without knowing these basic terms and understanding what they mean. You can't even search for more information unless you know the correct terms.

As such, it makes sense to introduce these fundamental terms, along with a definition/explanation, in the introductory topic. It just so happens that C++ is a difficult language. No one ever promised it would be easy to program. The alternative would just be showing the "Hello, world" code *with no explanation*, and I can't see how that would be better for anyone.

It's also worth keeping in mind that the target audience for Stack Overflow itself is "professional and enthusiast programmers". We assume a basic level of technical knowledge, so we do not need to define terms like "file I/O" or "console", because you are expected to come to the table with that knowledge. Documentation on Stack Overflow is not for teaching my grandmother how to program. It's for teaching competent computer users who already know at least one other language (or at least have a basic understanding of one) a new language/tool/concept.

Besides, if you come across something in Documentation that you do not understand, then there is this great Q&A site attached to it that you can use to ask about it. As far as I'm concerned, that's the *real* innovation here. If all documentation had good Q&A, Stack Overflow would be out of business.

For what it's worth, I recall many moons ago when Documentation was first released to the public, we had <strike>an argument</strike> some discussion about how to include compilation instructions along with the "Hello, world" example.

The problem is that every compiler and build environment is different, and there's just no way to include a description of even the most common ones. Someone had contributed an explanation of building on Linux using GCC, and then someone else wanted to contribute an explanation of building on Windows using Visual C++, and then someone else wanted to contribute an explanation of building on Windows using MinGW, and on and on. Talk about *complicated*—installers, file extensions, compiler flags, Makefiles, executing binaries, oh my! And what happens when someone inevitably tries to contribute a how-to on compiling in Turbo C++ because "this is what we use at my school"?

So it was decided that this didn't belong in *language* documentation. It kind of hurts the "Hello, world" spirit, since you can't actually say hello to the world in C++ without being able to build the C++ code, but again, no one said programming is easy. As a compromise, we have a link to an online push-button compiler, no installation required. And a separate new [Compiling and Building](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4708/compiling-and-building#t=201705120754522023697) topic was created, where examples for each compiler/system can be added. It isn't as good as it being right there in the "Hello, world" topic, but there just isn't any way to do it in the restrictive model of Documentation. If you have a different idea on how to address this impasse, please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: *teaching competent computer users* is little bit broad, isn't it? Anyway +1

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that a **target audience** has properly been defined for Documentation.

I believe the original purpose as advertised was to "cover gaps in existing documentation", which would indicate any audience where there isn't sufficient documentation out there already for them. So **any audience** is probably the most correct answer.

I personally believe that all the "Hello World" examples are evidence of Documentation's failure—it's duplicating existing content (something that SO explicitly set out not to do), and I believe these topics only exist so people can try and get quick reputation gains, unfortunately.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I'm obviously trying to type too fast if my grammar needs editing :/ Feel free to comment and I'll go fix it next time :)

Comment: A comment would be a waste of time. If I noticed it, I can fix it just as easily as I can bug you with a comment.