# Is Documentation a failed experiment?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Early on, I made some small change to some small part of PHP Documentation and occasionally see a single rep point pop up, but I NEVER find myself visiting it for ANY reason now.

[Matteo Italia's well upvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347978/1195835) to a question about improving Documentation said "...just stop caring." and "don't waste your time trying to fix it, just let it die"

If this is the general consensus of SO users, has the time come to pull the proverbial plug on it?

Comment: SE's response to pretty much all of the criticism of Documentation has been to ignore it, rather than fixing any of the problems.  They've pretty strongly indicated that they're not going to pull it because *they* think it's successful, despite most of the site regulars disagreeing.  Presumably this is because it's getting lots of views, even though subject matter experts feel it doesn't have quality content, and that's enough for SE.

Comment: @Servy We haven't done a great job communicating here, but the internal perception is emphatically *not* that it's a huge success and everything is great. We definitely realize it needs some improving and we should come out with some updates on the roadmap soon.

Comment: @Servy: "*SE's response to pretty much all of the criticism of Documentation has been to ignore it*" Not all of their response to criticism has been to ignore it. Sometimes they acknowledge it but then say "just wait, it'll work out."

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339391/is-documentation-failing

Comment: @DavidFullerton: "*we definitely realize it needs some improving*" My concern is really that the SE staff has not demonstrated an understanding of the problems and flaws of the Docs.SO system, both conceptually and implementation-wise. Whenever these flaws are enumerated, we're generally told that we don't understand the system, or that people will figure out how to use it better, or something dismissive like that. You cannot improve a system if you cannot acknowledge what is actually wrong with it. Not merely that it isn't working (anyone can see that), but *why* it isn't working.

Comment: I took an interest in docs because I saw that the docs for modding Minecraft with Forge was rather poor (to the point of having an invalid JSON file as an example, submitting a PR to have it fixed, have it accepted, and then a week later it was *reverted* in another update).  So I eagerly supported the addition of the Minecraft docs site, which has only just begun to pick up some articles. Mostly because I don't think people know how the format is supposed to work. I even got told yesterday that "Forge modding should be on its own docs" which doesn't exist. Apparently Minecraft == Bukkit now?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, you can argue that we're incompetent, but at least we're not ignoring the fact that it's not working right now and pretending everything is okay :) Throwing everything away and starting over with a different format (as [you've suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339987/91687)) is always a possibility, but we'd really like to fix what we've got if at all possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas, we do acknowledge that some of the specific concerns you've raised (about what a "topic" - or other units should be) are almost certainly part of the current challenge to the sysem.  We are looking hard at what needs to be clearer (in guidance) and what needs to be different (in  structure, naming, etc.)  But as David pointed out, we haven't always done enough to share our thinking.  We'll do better there.

Comment: I watched Documentation from its proposal, through its various stages, with interest. Not because I understood it, I thought from the beginning that it seemed to be an ill-defined solution in search of a convincing problem. I was honestly hoping to be proven wrong, and I'm far from happy to be – so far as I can currently see – right.

Comment: @Draco18s: What are you talking about? Can you provide some links? For instance, what is "the Minecraft docs site"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was running into character limits, but sure. First [the bad Forge documentation](http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blockstates/forgeBlockstates/#sub-models). Notice how the JSON file uses `1: { }` instead of `"1": { }` Despite flagging the issue it still hasn't been fixed (also the fact that JSON does not allow comments). Per the comment, it is now gone (side effect of the article being moved?) [but it did happen](https://s30.postimg.org/58ojlcjbl/forge.png) ([and the url that inbox item links to](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/9739))

Comment: If you brows the rest of Forge's docs, see if you can understand [capabilities](http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastorage/capabilities/) (say, creating your own) or [this lovely section](http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blocks/interaction/#player-breakdestroy). There's an entire forum dedicated to providing help and Capabilities (including what they're even *for*) comes up on a near-daily basis.

Comment: How do you even get to SO documentation?

Comment: @Ungeheuer: Maybe the big link at the top of every SO page, labelled "Documentation"?

Comment: There needs to be some sort of incentivization in the form of reputation. The only examples that get upvotes are the ones that have a significant amount of upvotes already. Hence there is no incentive from a rep standpoint, to improve examples that will not be seen/upvoted (most exs in docs).  Funny thing is the ones that have the most upvotes (highest probability to earn future upvotes) are immaculate. Very well formatted, with great information written in a succinct manner. If you want docs to be great, you got to incentivize behaviors with reputation. Anything short of that will not succeed

Comment: @Jaydles But you *never* acknowledge the criticisms that the project is poorly motivated or that the experts won't engage or that the site will silt up with rubbish, all of which you were told a year ago. SO continues to think of it as something that just needs more tweaking. The problems are far deeper than that, and they are mostly intrinsic.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition That would be true. Just noticed. Perhaps that's just another nail in the coffin of this feature.

Comment: The only reason I remember Documentation is still a thing are the occasional notifications that somebody has proposed a change to a topic I contributed to ages ago and have long given up on. They would have been reviewed by the time I see the notifications, and I have no way of disassociating from the topic so I stop seeing them in the first place, so I don't care about them anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock: "*I have no way of disassociating from the topic*" Actually, you can. Go to the discussion page for that topic and unselect the "watch all discussions" thing.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Neat, thanks. Was that there before? If so, well, that's how you know how far detached I've been from Docs altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock It was there, but that's not enough to stop *all* notifications. You'll also need to check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=documentation) and click 'watching' and unwatch each discussion (added in Feb). Then you'll need to go the the documentation *dashboard* and turn off all notifications for each topic. Easy! *cough* Extra helpful that [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-notifications) makes no mention of the watching tab

Comment: Even after reading all the meta posts on the topic I am still not sure what problems docs is supposed to solve and how. Having said that, since the infrastructure is already in place it could be renamed to "example based cookbook" and it could be at least used to dump code examples that do not easily fit into the QA format. But as the saying goes, "everything has been said but not everyone  has said it", so even that suggestion has already been made dozens of times.

Comment: Haven't we had this post several times already? Yes it is a failure, let it die in peace.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it's for and the reward (both implicit and explicit) for contributing to anything besides the most highly frequented topics is non existant. Why would I spend hours writing a introductory example on something when barely anyone will see it?

Comment: What I've never understood since the start of Documentation is the sheer unbridled **hatred** some users have for it on this site. When I read posts like this and see some of the comments, I can only conclude Documentation killed their children for the anger they have towards it.

Comment: I can;t claim any such hatred, but it's been my observation that the ones with most animosity towards Documentation tend to be those who work hard to establish and maintain their reputation. The award of rep for contributions to Docs appears to be incommensurate with the amount of effort expended, and no penalty appears to be imposed for inaccurate or misleading contributions.

Comment: My own experience is that topics tend to become "full" of drivel that runs the risk of misleading those wishing to learn. Further contribution attempts are then rejected with cries of ["no room!"](http://www.alice-in-wonderland.net/resources/chapters-script/alices-adventures-in-wonderland/chapter-7/)

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the purpose of docs is.

Comment: @SGR: "*What I've never understood since the start of Documentation is the sheer unbridled hatred some users have for it on this site.*" Docs.SO is 1) a poorly conceived feature, 2) many people told them it was poorly conceived, 3) is implemented badly, 4) we told them it was implemented badly in the beta, 5) yet despite all of this, they keep moving forward with it. This kind of pig-headed determination to cling to bad ideas tends to engender hatred from the people those ideas are being foisted on.

Comment: It didn't fail, we just found one method that doesn't work.

Comment: @NicolBolas "tends to engender hatred from the people those ideas are being foisted on" - how is this service is being "foisted" on anyone? Regardless of whether it's a good idea or how well it's implemented, it's entirely possible to use SO without ever going anywhere near it. I get that some people disagree with how it's been implemented but this kind of attitude is just childish and certainly not constructive.

Comment: @Nathan: Even if you ignore the big "Documentation Beta" button at the top, it affects rep gaining significantly, leading to many people having Q&A privileges that they didn't effectively earn. People are reviewing edits to SO who haven't the slightest idea how Q&A works. I would consider that being "foisted on" everyone.

Comment: @Nathan Except that its taking developer (and other) resources from something we know that works, to chase something that is failing miserably.  It was possibly worthy of a trial (although I think they went to trial with their plans half baked and code unprepared, making it a complete waste), but its time to admit it failed and stop wasting resources on a failure-  or at least hit the pause button while you reset for a VERY different and more organized v2.

Comment: @SGR It doesn't advance the debate in any way to start throwing the H word around. You would do better to start addressing the entirely rational comments and answers that have been posted about it since inception. It is pointless to have a discussion if it is going to descend to nonsense like this.

Comment: I had high hopes for it when it was first announced, but after participating in the beta, seeing the layout and reading the introductory post about documentation I realised it was doomed to fail. That was the point where I stepped away.

Comment: When you come to realise that even w3schools is a better documentation portal then SO.Docs, something is seriously wrong with the approach.

Comment: Something that is stated here in the comments and in other answers/comments here is that Documentation isn't needed because there are already examples on Stackoverflow for most things one would ever need. While this is correct, there is one big problem: Changes between versions in a library. I may find how problem X was solved six years ago but that probably won't work today. The documentation site would solve this problem.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler It would only solve it if people actively updated the Docs with each release of a library. I don't see that happening. There's nothing stopping a user from asking a question like "How do I solve X in version Y?" with a link to the solution for version Z.

Comment: @MikeC true but, if done right, there could be, similiar to the MSDN, subsections for versions with explanations/examples on what changed. That would be 'cleaner' than what you suggested (which would work, of course)

Comment: @Lankymart: Hey, that's [my line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339391/is-documentation-failing#comment420642_339430)! (But seriously, I'm glad I'm not the only one.)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler There is no reason that answers to StackOverflow questions can't be updated when things change.

Comment: I think the name itself killed it. Most serious programmers i know of, including yours truly, wouldn't even consider any work that includes _documentation_ in the task list.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I dunno. Common sense seemed to dictate that it'd be unsuccessful from the start and shouldn't have been attempted. I mean, you already had documentation, kept up to date by product maintainers, in an organized fashion, easily searchable through a single text box in your browser, i.e., the internet. Then SE thought it would be a good idea to task random users with maintaining a redundant copy of something that already existed and was easily accessible, and expected that to add something to the internet? It's basically Wikipedia meets archive.org with the QC of W3Schools...

Comment: I mean, just ask yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, or http://php.net/docs.php? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, or https://api.jquery.com/? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation, or http://google.com? You get the drift. The choices should've been clear before you guys dedicated development resources to it. My browser's address bar search > SO docs search box, in all cases.

Comment: For me,i don't like the idea of merging both reputations

Comment: What is the point of making yet another meta post...? Is your question seriously just "Documentation sucks, amirite?"

Comment: @whrrgarbl No, My question, spurred by seeing a great number of upvotes on an answer suggesting that we "let it die", was intended to 1) Find out if the community in general actually considers it a failure, and 2) To suggest that if it actually is a failure that the SO company considers removing it as it's just clutter. Now, what the SO company decides to do is entirely up to them, but our voices matter, a little.

Comment: @Fattie SO is also "the" place to find gibbering idiots posting complete nonsense - and it's been that way since 2008. The key difference is that SO's Q&A model embraces *competition* - it doesn't matter if people make terrible contributions because they'll get downvoted and other people's good contributions will become more visible. Documentation lacks a system of *competition*, and so it fundamentally *has to solve the quality filtering problem* in a way that Q&A never did; SO Q&A can be an incredible resource even if 95% of what gets posted is shite, but Documentation doesn't work that way.

Comment: hi Mark, yes you're totally correct. I would say further: even setting aside the "competition" aspect: say you go to a certain SO QA page. There's some gems and a lot of dross. One can - even if there was no voting - easily discern and dismiss the dross and gain ultra-critical information from the gems. As you point out, the only value of the documentation site is that: ***the documentation 'product' is a sort of scientific demonstration of how well the existing SO QA pages work***.  IE, they completely took away the thing that makes SO work, and fully proved that the result is worthless.

Comment: It's [official](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4751173) - the answer is yes.

Comment: Mark Amery's point is very incisive. I always had the feeling that Documentation was an attempt at the no-downvoting bananas-for-everyone utopian summer-of-lovefest dream that I always seem to hear lurking behind the words of some SE staff. Hopefully it's completely clear now how well that works out.

Comment: Mark Amery's point is indeed very incisive, and finally made me understand both how SO manages to work, and why Doc.SO failed. @JoshCaswell: you are also correct that there is a certain Goldilocks quantity of criticism and aggression needed to weed out bad content, and that a moderate level of nastiness is more healthy than none at all.

Comment: [*Documentation* was sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) in August 2017.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

How do you determine if it has failed? There are so many standards by which you could measure the current functionality of Docs.SO as a system.

So let us look at the foundation document for Docs.SO: [Warlords of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?rq=1). It enumerates four broad problems with documentation, so let's see if we've succeeded at any of them:

> 1. Documentation is often an afterthought, obviously done just to say that it exists, with little concern for its quality. We've all seen plenty of this in our time. We can bring a focus on quality, peer review, and "actually solves real problems for real developers"-ness to documentation that would be very welcome.

I would say that, objectively speaking, quality on Docs.SO is... scattershot. I'm sure there are some good examples out there, and even whole topics that are decent. But as a whole, I'd say that whatever quality is there is drowning under a tide of (at best) mediocrity. And plagiarism.

Peer review on Docs.SO? *Complete and utter failure*. The fact that it takes just any 4 individuals to allow anything on the site, even when *none of them has the specific domain knowledge or is otherwise a suitable reviewer*, shows the failure of this system. This is a non-trivial part of the lack of quality of Docs.SO.

As for solving "real problems for real developers"... I'd say that Docs.SO by and large doesn't do that. Topics tend to be more of the "basic documentation" variety rather than anything problem or task focused. As such, examples more often than not demonstrate how a tool works, not how you're supposed to use it to accomplish something useful.

So overall, #1 is a bust.

> 2. Often documentation is **lacking in examples**, or the examples are trivial and don't demonstrate typical use. Because Stack Overflow benefits from constant feedback from developers writing real-world code, we could greatly improve the quantity and quality of examples. Let's be honest: finding examples is *already* a common use-case for Stack Overflow; we might as well embrace it.

Docs.SO is example-focused documentation. In a technical sense; the meat of topics are called examples.

However, most examples on Docs.SO are not "real-world code". They're artificial, used to explain a specific point. They show off how to use a method or a class or something of that sort. But very little of it is something from "real-world code".

So #2 doesn't seem to be any good either.

> 3. Much of the documentation out there is tied to release cycles, and thus **infrequently updated and rarely "complete"**. The community-contributed and edited nature of Stack Overflow would be an immediate improvement.

It's hard to evaluate how well Docs.SO handles being out of date. It does however acknowledge that versions are things that exists, and provides tools that allow users to add version-specific information.

However, considering the [low participation in Docs.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339440/734069), it is highly unlikely that, as new releases of software are made, Docs.SO will be updated in anything like a comprehensive fashion. So as time passes, Docs.SO will become increasingly out-of-date.

This isn't a structural problem so much as a participation problem. If Docs.SO were actively maintained by a set of energetic and skilled hands, this would probably work out.

> 4. A lot of documentation descends from Javadocs, and while it was better than nothing in '96, **it's hard to call framesets with unshareable URLs "good" in 2015**. We can focus on creating the best UX for creating and serving documentation on the modern web.

This is probably more subjective than most, but quite frankly, I'll take JavaDoc organization over Docs.SO any day of the week. Oh sure, you can link directly to an example, or to the syntax or remarks section. You can even link directly to a specific version, to ensure that you're showing off something that won't change.

But if you need to know what a function does, it's still a lot easier to find a JavaDoc page on it than the appropriate Docs.SO article. Docs.SO's search is horrible, which makes finding specific information essentially impossible. You can't just type in a class/function name and expect to find something on it.

JavaDoc may have terrible HTML, but if you know the class and member function that's causing a problem, you can at least *find* their crappy documentation about it. We can't even get that far.

So, is Docs.SO a failure? I would say that there's good evidence that it has yet to accomplish any of the stated goals of the project.

Comment: Based on what I think Docs is _supposed_ to be (examples, not Javadoc), a better comparison would be the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html), which can be navigated and linked into just fine.  Here's the page on [Swing combo boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), for example.  I got there by following the hierarchy, but I could also have Ctrl-F'd on the [Really Big Index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), and of course Google indexes it.  So point 4 can't really be improved upon, anyway.

Comment: "The fact that it takes just 4 idiots to allow anything on the site shows the failure of this system" - this has been a large part of my problem with SO (especially but not only the review part) for years...

Comment: @Dukeling: But Q&A reviewing at least requires 2000 rep. Anyone who just registered is able to approve Docs.SO changes.

Comment: #1: The entire existence of Docs.so is an afterthought, by definition. It is intrinsically impossible for StackOverflow to solve that problem. #2 'Lacking in examples' is not a sufficient motivation for deciding that there should be another whole system that is example-*based*. #3 'Tied to release cycles' is exactly what documentation should be. No real problem is being addressed here. #4 Yet another straw man. Javadoc does not consist of 'unshareable links', and there are many thousands of SO posts that prove it. Again no real problem is being addressed here. These motivations are all void.

Comment: 'Spurious' would a better word. The project has failed for reasons which were comprehensively predicted a year ago: it is poorly motivated; the experts won't engage; and it will silt up with rubbish, which is exactly what has happened.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: Of course, thanks to the misleading name "Documentation" many people think it's a place to find API documentation or step-by-step tutorials anyways, so the comparison to Javadoc probably isn't that far off. Just look at all the other tags whose "Documentation" consists primarily of content copied from official manuals.

Comment: But you can link directly to any section in JavaDoc... they've all got anchors etc.

Comment: The fact that any post with this in it: "The fact that it takes just 4 idiots to allow anything on the site shows the failure of this system" gets so many upvotes reveals why SO has degenerated into a horrible place.  Why do we continue using this thing?  We could make something that actually was focused on knowledge that required civil exchange.  Maybe we should do that?

Comment: @codewise: "*We could make something that actually was focused on knowledge that required civil exchange.*" Would you feel better if I called them "intellectually challenged?" You're ignoring the main point (ie: low quality of information due to people approving changes who have no idea what they're doing) to dither over a matter of what we call such people.

Comment: @NicolBolas The tone is what scares learners away from this SO.  I agree that documentation should be peer-reviewed and perhaps the requirements should be more stringent.  But name calling is essentially a form of attack.  It does not help anyone.

Comment: "4 people who lack specific domain knowledge" @codewise

Comment: I think that documentation came about way too late because the majority of the projects i use (in my experience) have good documentation (in fact i rarely find myself using SO anymore) so i don't need a site that brings together (or rather sporadically copies and pastes) documentation from those projects. The only projects that I find have poor documentation tend to be smaller projects where i either add it myself or read the code (a smaller code base is more accessible). So I think unfortunately by the time documentation came around the problem of documentation is not so big anymore.

Comment: And the reason a project doesn't have good documentation is probably because the community that uses it is not motivated enough to add it so I cannot see why they would be anymore motivated to add it to SO if they won't do it within the project itself.

Comment: @CodyGray: The problem with "people who lack specific domain knowledge" is that such people are not the problem. The problem are people who lack specific domain knowledge, yet are arrogant enough to believe that they actually know enough about that domain to review the work of others. Ignorance alone is not the problem, so the description is not accurate.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Since people with domain knowledge [did not review changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339140/1438), I don't know what system of review will meet your criteria. Perhaps we'd be better off without required reviews _à la_ WIkipedia.

Comment: At this point we should really just rename Documentation to Code or Code Snippets and remove all the 'doc' verbiage and just focus solely on examples of how to do certain popular things in a given language. Oh, and for starters, users should require at least a thousand rep to suggest an example, and have a bronze badge in the tag in order to review suggestions, with gold badgers obviously able to unilaterally approve/reject suggestions and make unilateral edits.

Comment: @JonEricson So... WikiCode?

Comment: @TylerH "_examples of how to do certain popular things in a given language_"  So something like Rosetta Code, but 'transposed', such that examples are listed by language/library and not by task?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I've never heard of Rosetta Code, so I couldn't say

Comment: It'a a good point that official documentation tends to be more of a reference with few real-world examples. They tend to focus on the question of "what?" rather than "how?". SO Q & A is great but quite rightly limits the scope of each question so I can see there is a need for something like SO.doc. However I agree it needs to be be better structured with more QC. Perhaps renaming it Cookbook and limiting it examples would be a good idea but then we are getting very close to RosettaCode.org or gists on github.

Answer (score 104):

In my humble opinion, the answer is unequivocally **yes**. It is a failed experiment.

I thought Documentation was a solution in search of a problem from when it was first announced. But I didn't complain on Meta, I simply decided to wait and see if it would actually work. I think it's time to admit it doesn't.

I've used Stack Overflow regularly since 2009, I'm in the top 0.7% of reputation or something like that, and I'm ostensibly a subject matter expert.

I am also amazingly passionate about software documentation, and I work hard to ensure that APIs I create and projects I maintain are well documented. Fifteen-ish years ago I even worked professionally as a technical writer for a while. So this kind of thing would seem to be right up my alley.

But I have literally never used the Documentation feature.

Not only have I never *contributed* to Documentation, I have never even *used* it. An internet search for documentation -- about literally anything I have ever searched for -- has never turned up Documentation as one of the top hits. stackoverflow.com comes up all the time. Other curated document sets on GitHub, readthedocs.io, or other sites come up all the time. Stack Overflow Documentation? Nope.

Every time I start to wonder if Documentation is worth my time, I see posts about what a tragic mess it is. If I'm going to invest in documenting a project, I'll contribute to the official documentation, thank you very much.

And if I'm *consuming* documentation, I'm going to look for high-quality, authoritative material. And I hate to say it, but Stack Overflow Documentation isn't going to be where I find it.

Comment: I think they are deliberately keeping it away from the search engines, since it is supposedly still in beta state. If Documentation were to pop up in search engine results, it would probably mean that SO as whole would lose a lot of credibility and get lower rank.

Comment: Like you, I am something of an expert in certain technologies, and passionate about both documentation and accuracy. Unlike you, I actually *did* try to use Documentation. It was an unabashed failure. The misinformation, plagiarized content, and sheer garbage poured in (and was approved by others who were similarly ill-informed) faster than I could ever hope to deal with it. The UI was actively hostile in many ways. The project's purpose was ill-conceived and remains ill-defined, define earnest pleas—is it a "cookbook" of examples or API "documentation" in the traditional sense? No one knows.

Comment: SO documentation is hosted under `stackoverflow.com` URN, therefore, when more relevant resources exist on SO main part, they will be displayed first. Google likes displaying one result per site, and indeed documentation won't show due to many reasons, probably including tailored parser for SO Q&A on Google side.

Comment: So long story short: the experiment failed because you have never used it.

From my perspective, Chinese is a failed experiment.

Comment: @Sherlock: That's not quite a fair characterization of my post. A better metaphor would be: If I, a person who is deeply interested in communicating with Chinese people, have never found any use for the Chinese language when actually communicating with Chinese people, *then* the Chinese language could be considered a failed experiment. SO Documentation is clearly in a very different situation than the Chinese language!

Comment: My point was that your answer is an argumentum ad verecundiam. It lacks analysis of the actual experiment (see Nicol Bolas' answer).

Answer (score 98):

I haven't been closely involved with the Documentation project. I've been watching it from afar with some interest, and I pitched in here on meta for a few weeks after the public beta rolled out, but outside of a few really frustrating discussions about reputation I haven't really been a part of the design or direction. So... I'm not particularly qualified to talk about it. But hey, that's never stopped me before... And there's something really critical missing from this discussion.

See, I've been watching this thread for a couple days now, and something's really bugging me about the responses. Specifically, the responses from employees of Stack Overflow The Company. They're all... kinda myopic.

I don't mean that as a put-down; the executives, project manager and community manager involved here are all doing their best to provide accurate, specific context for how we're viewing this project, what we're trying to achieve and how we're trying to approach that. And it's all *really good information* - **if you already know where we're coming from**.

But, you probably *don't* know that. There's, what, a year and a half worth of *really dense* meta posts, blog posts, answers, comments, speculation and discussion surrounding this project now, and nobody got time for that. Also... Even if you read all of it, you kinda had to read between the lines to figure out what was *really* going on.

So... I'm gonna try to provide some context, and *then* I'll try to answer your question.

### Too long, won't read

If you're already bored, stop reading this answer and [go read this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343678/whats-documentation-for/343704#343704). Come back only if you don't understand that answer... Or don't believe it.

What follows is my personal take on where this whole "Documentation" thing comes from, and where it's going. As is my tradition, it is long, rambling, and full of digressions... You have been warned.

### The chaotic money machine

Years ago, long-time SO/SE member jmort253 pointed me to [this entertaining talk from Mailchimp founder Ben Chestnut](https://youtu.be/bwR36YJ3S68?t=19m19s). One part in particular stuck with me, since it describes one of the primary challenges facing both Stack Overflow the Q&A site *and Stack Overflow the company*. It's a fun video, but for the sake of those who don't have 40 minutes to burn I'm gonna quote the relevant bit from a transcript I found [on Chris Barber's blog](http://blog.chrisbarber.co/transcript-creative-mornings-with-ben-chestnut):

> An entrepreneur has an idea usually. He wants to start a company. A business is like the steam machine like you don’t know how this works. You start up a business. You're like, "Oh, if I tweak this knob, I think money comes out."
>
> If I adjust the screw or like maybe make the pulley or something tighter like more money will come out. That's the first couple of years and then after a little while, you're like, "Wait a minute. Wait a minute. Wait a minute." Two knobs. What happens then like, "Holy shit. Wow. ..." Then, you're like, "Wow, man. I kind of get this stuff. This is kind of cool." Now, I'm going to start thinking big like Richard Branson big. You start learning about key performance indicators like my KPIs are all like knobs. I'm like him but knobs on top of knobs and I've got knobs down here and then like bam.

*[...]*

> Things go wrong when that original entrepreneur, the creative guy, says,
>
> "You know what? I deserve a break. I'm going to delegate now. The business is running itself. I can sort of like step back a little bit. Hands off."

*[...]*

> The thing is, your managers back at the office like, "What do I do with this thing?" He didn’t leave a manual. I don’t operate this stuff. I just protect so I'm going to hire robots and they're going to guard it. That's what I do.

*[...]*

> Before you know it, your whole company is thinking like managers. You're not all managers but you're thinking like managers. You're defending the money machine that you made 10 years ago. No one's making new machines. No one's looking to improve it. You're just defending, defending against competition, whatever. You're just in defense mode and even worse, the creative people at the bottom, they're like, "Wow! The only way to move up in this company is to become a manager or think like a manager."

We pretty much had the whole "programmer Q&A" thing ticking along 8 years ago. There was still a lot of optimization to be done, a lot of knob-turning and such, figuring out how to scale it up and make it run smoothly... But the basic *engine* was running; it worked, it made money, it *generated a repository of knowledge*. Not very much knowledge, but... Enough to demonstrate the concept. Six years ago, that pile of knowledge was a lot bigger... And we were starting to see that defensive thinking set in, both in the folks here on meta and within the company. Today, we have millions of users and hundreds of employees **who all depend on this machine running constantly, consistently, every day 24/7**. Changing anything that might threaten that operation requires getting past row after row of guards, on the site, here on meta, and within the company itself. We're *all* in "defense mode":

[image: diagram from that video showing a machine being protected by a silly amount of auxiliary stuff]

The changes that *do* get made have to work around or compensate for deficiencies in all of the stuff that *doesn't* change; the end result of this is [a huge, impossibly complicated system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084) that few fully understand and where no one can predict what changing it will actually do.

At some level, anyone who's been around more than 5 minutes knows that this is problematic, that we're ossifying, burning out, expending all of our energy [just to maintain position](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling)...

### Pasta on the wall

More than ever, we need to be trying new things, looking for new solutions to old problems and unmet challenges to rise to. At the same time, it has never been harder to actually try *anything*. The crushing presence of [an immense critical audience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617) awaits; one step more and the guard dogs will be snapping at your femoral artery.

You don't have to look hard to see the signs of this: the unchanging "Ask Question" page, ancient editor, total lack of any encouragement for experienced members to maintain aging information... Anything that might cause the machine to stall becomes untouchable. We all know it's a problem *even as we're all **part of** the problem!*

So a few years back, some folks within the company decided to push in a different direction: if we can't experiment on the main Q&A system, let's build *new* systems, and test ideas that way. Let's throw a whole bunch of pasta against the wall & see what sticks. Will it be mentoring? Videos? Teams? Stories? International sites? Documentation? Dancing?

And so the call went out: come up with an idea, convince your co-workers to try it, convince the exec team to try it, then convince meta. Then build it & see what happens...

[image: A guy in a park, dancing in front of a tablet to log in. Sometimes, pasta is messy.]

### Trust us: we think we don't know what we're doing

If all of this sounds kinda crazy... Maybe even a little bit irresponsible... You got the right idea. We're in defense-mode for a *reason* after all; a lot of the ideas folks have been proposing are *kinda dangerous*; if we tried 'em on Q&A, they probably *would* break things badly, so it shouldn't surprise anyone to see that when we try 'em in Documentation they *are* breaking. The big difference is... We can still fix them. **And we can learn something from the experience *without destroying 9 years of work in the process*.**

Stack Overflow Q&A today looks *nothing* like it did in the early days. The [most popular questions on the site in early '09](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20090227023005/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions?sort=votes) were those about cartoons, hidden features, jokes, and *questions about Stack Overflow the site itself!* It's pretty safe to say that if you took a regular SO user today, transported them back in time and dropped them into the site during its first year... They would be horrified by the lack of focus and *utter chaos* that reigned supreme during those days... Then they would be delighted by the lack of restrictions... Then they would be dismayed by the lack of useful information.

We got the site we have today *because* we tried a bunch of stuff early on, and learned from our mistakes. We need to be able to keep doing that.

### Finally, the answer to your question: has Documentation failed?

**Yes!** Several times, in fact. I'd give you a laundry-list, but as I said at the outset there are a bunch of folks way more qualified to talk about this than me; instead, I'll point out perhaps the most blatant example:

**Reputation was utterly broken at the launch of the beta.** No sugar-coating it; the rep system in place at the start of the public beta was completely unworkable, and fell apart within *days*. What'd we learn from this? Exactly what we'd suspected since literally the private beta of Stack Overflow back in '08: that awarding reputation for editing is *really, really problematic.* Which is why we never ventured to touch that hornets' nest in Q&A; it *would* have broken everything. With Docs, we had the chance to test it, and fix it. (I'm not at all convinced that we have it right just yet, but we have made a LOT of progress)

If you're patting yourself on the back right now for knowing ahead of time that the rep system was broken... So am I; it makes it hard to type. Also, it's a bogus attitude - neither of us *knew* it would fail, we just made an educated guess - now we have actual experimental evidence, copious detail on *exactly* how it failed. If we ever want to make concrete improvements, the latter is *infinitely* more useful than the former. I'm sure Jon and Kevin and Vasudha have a *long* list of other failures - and what we've learned from them, *and* what we're gonna do to avoid them in the future.

### In closing

It took at least a couple of *years* before the "best of" Stack Overflow didn't look like a joke. An awful lot of folks gave up on it before then, either because they didn't have the time to stick it out or because it was turning into something completely different from the site they thought they'd signed up for. If we stick with Documentation that long, I fully expect to see the same thing happen... But **even without that rosy future**, I'm excited that we're finally making big mistakes and learning from them again, turning knobs and seeing what happens. And even if you don't ever intend to use Documentation, you should be excited about that too. [Everyone needs a little bit of chaos...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWnTJjAKwdY)

Comment: `Will it be mentoring? Videos? Teams? Stories? International sites? Documentation? Dancing?` I can only support dancing.

Comment: Now that said, I get it. Innovate all what you want. However, as you mentioned, failure has a cost and the cost is bigger now. For all the people who contributed to a failed project, they can loose faith in your ability to deliver. There are a number of ways to manage innovation, there are books on that, I wont repeat all of it here. One way is to spin things off. For instance, having docs as a separate experimental thing. The irresponsible attitude is `move fast, break things` which still seems to be in vogue. Throw things in the air and see what sticks. It is fine when you dont have a budget

Comment: Literally nothing could be changed the first few weeks of the public beta since people weren't watching tags. (This was a problem in the private beta too, but not nearly as many people tried to make changes, so it wasn't as noticeable.) The situation only improved when we [put Docs in the global review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334300/fyi-new-documentation-review-queue-for-proposed-changes). On the other hand, [Markdown tables seem kinda ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328989/adding-the-table-markdown-from-documentation-to-qa).

Comment: so that is a clear path for cash-starved start-ups. But when you have cash, you can afford to do it the regular time-proven way. Define your concept, the value proposition, the target market, validate the product/market fit through focus groups or else, and so on, and so forth. I cant sugar coat it either. SO Docs did not receive the level of study that is necessary to ensure its success. It really looks like the idea of one guy, and lets see what gives. There is nothing to be proud of here. When you roll out a product to millions of people, you want to have done your homework before.

Comment: I think SO should include a different profile of people in your team, away from the maverick visionary who changes the world, towards a pluri-disciplinary team which include not only technical people but also marketing people, and community leaders. SO Docs shows in my mind a lack of conceptual thinking and a lot of focus on the technical side of things, with the constraint to reuse as much as possible of the existing platform which precisely restricts the ability to approach the problem with a fresh mind. Forget about SO. How would you crack Doc? You might have found another start-up there.

Comment: Funny thing, @user3743222... I'm pretty sure Docs has been focus-group-tested more than any other part of Stack Overflow, *ever*. If memory serves, focus groups delayed the original launch by *months*. Focus groups have their place, but they don't tell you how something is gonna be used by a few hundred people all hammering on it at once. Focus groups don't tell you that your incentive system is gonna fall apart at scale - they may even encourage poor incentives. Surveys & little test groups & interviews all have their place, but they don't magically replace *people hammering away in earnest*.

Comment: focus groups is not the only technique used to validate product/market fit. I mention it because it is the most commonly known tool for the marketer. My point is a lot of these issues are actually predictable, there is a bunch of litterature, case studies and what not on the subject. But you need to have marketing at a sufficient high-level of decisional power.

Comment: (also, I know I kinda invited this by linking to a Ben Chestnut video... But *please* let's not make this a HackerNews "I know how to make any business work but my own" thread)

Comment: I was not aware this is what I was doing. Anyways, the result of whatever process have been followed is there for all to see. An important question among others is how to improve that process, and those are just my 2 cents that I will keep for myself in the future.

Comment: Don't mean to be unkind here, @user3743222, but "get Marketing involved" isn't a process any more than "get Design involved" is a process. Marketing and design (and testing, and research, and SRE and legal and ...) aren't magic fairy dust that you sprinkle onto a project to make it work; they're parts of a team that can *assist* if they're involved from the start. FWIW, we've only had a marketing dept for SO for maybe 3 years, and Documentation and Developer Story are probably the projects they've been *most* involved in; they did good work, but... Not magic.

Comment: Oi! Smokey isn't a dirt bike! Smokey's a robot unicorn! Sure, both are largely metal, and you can ride both, but one has a point.

Comment: @Shog9: "*The most popular questions on the site in early '09*" I do not think that the most popular questions is a useful metric to determine if the site was useful or not. A better metric would be to look at the influx of new questions (at the time) and ask how many of them would be considered on-topic today. And whether they were getting good answers. Because if that is working (and it was), you simply need to eliminate the non-working parts. Right now, you can't point at anything in Docs.SO and claim that it's working as it should.

Comment: See, I disagree strongly about that, @Nicol. I was here in '09 - here for fun, because Stack Overflow was still completely worthless as a tool for doing my job and would continue to be for a fair bit longer. Folks weren't hand-wringing about that on meta, though... Because meta didn't exist. They weren't hand-wringing about that on Stack Overflow either. The Daily Whine was either, "career development questions are being closed unfairly" or "do we really need a Hidden Features of Notepad question?" - which just goes to show, we're all pretty myopic at times.

Comment: @Shog9: "*Stack Overflow was still completely worthless as a tool for doing my job and would continue to be for a fair bit longer.*" Why was that the case? Were questions about useful stuff being ignored, or was it difficult to find questions about useful stuff? Was it the lack of a categorization mechanism or something else that made it hard to find good questions? Because the list of popular questions is essentially irrelevant; nobody uses that to find questions to learn from or answer.

Comment: @shog9, well then after all that, letting out such an undefined concept, I dont know what exactly they were doing. I mean anything can fail, but something so massive, if you cant blame the process, blame the people, but blame something because you cant go out there and say that shit is fine and chaos is alright, and nothing could have been done differently as if this was unavoidable. That honestly makes me even more worried about the ability to reverse course

Comment: Show me one site on the Internet with a workable reputation system for editing (that is, one that tries to gauge the usefulness of edits and award or withhold a variable amount of reputation accordingly) that operates on even a tenth of the scale of Stack Overflow, and I'll be forever in your debt @user3743222. Otherwise, all this "you're doing it wrong" stuff is just talk.

Comment: Well now... If only this answer had been part of the original proposal. From the beginning I think a lot of people have been very confused about the purpose of Documentation above and beyond Stack Overflow Q&A. If I had known what I now know from reading this answer, I would have been much more supportive throughout. I get the idea that you need to be able to fail horribly to make a great product.

Comment: If you think the reputation system is the most important problem of DOC SO, you fail to understand how much of it is ill defined. Yes this is just talk, you can also call it feedback. You might agree or disagree with that feedback, naturally. But again, going around denying the obvious as this was a fatality does not help improving

Comment: *defensive thinking*, the new 6-8 weeks? ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's easy to say in hindsight @Nicol. And perhaps in another 9 years we'll be saying the same thing about the Java Arrays topic or whatever crap folks are fixating on in Docs. But that's what we were fixating on back then, for good or bad. As for why I didn't find SO useful... It was tiny compared to today, and most of the well-covered topics were pretty basic stuff. When I get stuck, it's not on something that's covered in the official docs or trivial to figure out in a debugger... So, took a year or so before SO accumulated enough depth to actually save me time.

Comment: The reputation system is the only bit I've actually had serious involvement with, and hence the only bit I'm even a little bit qualified to discuss @user3743222. That's... like the first paragraph of this answer. So, that's the example I used. I'm *pretty sure* the reputation system is fairly unique in terms of requirements, which means we don't have a nice playbook for making it work - that likely applies to other parts of the system as well, but I can't speak to them.

Comment: @Shog9: "*And perhaps in another 9 years we'll be saying the same thing about the Java Arrays topic or whatever crap folks are fixating on in Docs.*" But I'm not fixating on that. I don't judge Docs.SO based on the most popular, obviously broken topics. I [did a survey of quite a lot of topics of varying kinds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332369/734069). My view is not based on just the most popular stuff; it's fairly comprehensive. And it's not working to produce decent content.

Comment: @Shog9, If you talk about an algorithm for automatic assignment of individual rewards for community-edited content, that respects some constraints such as fairness, proportionality to value, and what not, I dont know much about that. That seems a pretty hard problem. Maybe somebody will figure it out. Maybe the problem is not solvable without relaxing a few of those constraints. Maybe the problem is not solvable at all. In any case, I do know community-edited content, which makes no use of rewards and still enjoy good success and reputations among its users.

Comment: Yeah, that was a good essay @Nicol. But it still kinda falls into "educated guess" territory; [at about that point in SO's history](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/12/a-question-about-questions/), we (collectively) thought "best practice" discussions were gonna be in the top-five categories of question on SO. Predicting the future is hard.

Comment: Seeing as how we've actually worked on it, I can tell you with certainty that it *is* a pretty hard problem, @user3743222. (now you should go read the rest of this answer, since I kinda said this already above!)

Comment: My point here is, maybe you are imposing this problem on yourself. SO Q&A is perfectly fine without attributing reputation for editing. Is there anybody complaining about that? Why try to fix something that has no problem? Maybe SO Docs needs no reputation system? The bias that comes from the experience of Q&A where the reputation did work (eventually, according to what you say) is that there needs to be a reputation system too for SO Docs. Maybe thats not the case. In any case, the first thing is to have a conceptually well-defined SO Docs, otherwise it is so much harder to reason about.

Comment: Oh, yeah, we absolutely 100% are imposing this problem on ourselves, @user3743222. That "rep for editing" thing was [first proposed in October of 2008](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/40930-gain-reputation-for-good-edits), and deemed too difficult; it's been asked for numerous times since then, with the same result, and for good reason. At the same time, each year editing becomes more and more important as the volume of incomplete or out-of-date information grows. So yeah... We went into this with eyes open; no pain, no gain.

Comment: SOCVR is the shredder of SO, hmm? Explains the permanent [ninja dog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) parked in the channel. I knew he was in cahoots with turtles...

Comment: I should also note that [failure is not necessarily a bad thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JA7G7AV-LT8)

Comment: So, I've seen a couple of employee answers say something like "Q&A isn't working (people won't self-answer, newbies find the rules inscrutable, ...), so we'll try something new", and this post seems to say Q&A is ossified, implying that the perennially-promised "quality project" that would improve question quality through better asker guidance or whatever won't happen.  That's disappointing, but understandable.  But Docs is moving slowly enough that I feel like it's already ossified too (especially because you built your own sort-of-wiki instead of using an existing one).  What did you gain?

Comment: *“come up with an idea, convince your co-workers to try it, convince the exec team to try it, **then convince meta**”* – I don’t think meta was *convinced* when the Docs project was originally announced. There were a lot of concerns and confusion about its purpose (it following the original Q/A idea of a knowledge database was never mentioned officially btw.). But the staff responses were mostly “just let us do our thing and you will see”, as if they always knew better. But even with the first beta they failed to answer most concerns; and meta kept staying largely unconvinced.

Comment: *“if we tried 'em on Q&A, they probably would break things badly […]”* – But the problem is that Docs was always integrated with Q&A. This was always a big problem of me personally, and I know others felt similar, and goes hand in hand with the reputation issue you mention later: Reputation on Docs was *utterly broken*, and I still think that it’s far from perfect today. But the fact that this affected the global Q&A reputation made this a huge problem, since it affected Q&A as well. That’s where you lost me and others with interest in Docs.

Comment: Q&A works, @jeffrey. But it is becoming an increasingly limited tool. We need to be able to build out improvements to it, but are limited in what we can try. Docs is moving at a breakneck pace by comparison. (I fear this is an unsatisfactory answer; ping me in chat if you wish)

Comment: I have a considerate background with wikis, and if I learned anything there it’s that gamification is not everything. Yes, gamification surely helped a lot to make SO Q&A attractive to people, and it likely wouldn’t work without it. But for something like Docs, that’s about maintaining quality content over a long time, you need people dedicated to the cause and the topic, not to some virtual points. As others said elsewhere, good documentation is mostly about good structure, but you do not get structure from many editors. Structure is usually decided by a small group of dedicated editors.

Comment: This answer sums up pretty well why I've always felt Documentation deserved defending against the "Y U DO NEW THINGS! Y U NOT FOCUS ON MAIN THING!!!!!" crowd even if it might ultimately end up failing.

Comment: Rep was recalculated, @poke. Numbers are relatively easy to change. Imagine the mess if we'd rolled that out for, say, answers.

Comment: *“I'm pretty sure Docs has been focus-group-tested more than any other part of Stack Overflow, ever.”* – That does not really explain why Docs – to me – has the worst kind of UX ever. To this date, I literally cannot navigate that thing properly, or figure out how all those different edit histories interlock with each other. It overall feels rather counter intuitive for its purpose (allowing easy edits, and proper reviewing of content changes).

Comment: Which just goes to show, you can take a very skilled designer, test the hell out of the resulting design in private, and *still* end up with something that doesn't really work for the actual target audience, @poke. As I said to user3743222 above, it's nice to have a good team and good tools, but ultimately the only test that matters is putting the result in front of a real audience and watching them tear it apart.

Comment: @Shog9 From the answer you linked to, it almost seems like you are saying that SO is a failed idea also. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorta, @Caleb. Stack Overflow has generated an *immense* volume of useful, practical solutions to programming problems, and thousands of new questions are answered every day - in that sense it is a success. **That success is no small feat!** At the same time... An awful lot of practical questions end up never being asked here, or remain unanswered; the depth of knowledge for small tags can be pitiful. There is a growing volume of noise that makes it hard to find useful information. There's a perception (somewhat exaggerated) that crowdsourced debugging is primary purpose. These are failures.

Comment: The danger here is that we've come to fear failure so much that we resist even trying to fix the problems lest we make them worse or break something else. That we become so protective of the areas in which we've succeeded that we dare not risk them by learning from the areas where we've failed, or even admitting that they exist.

Comment: If Documentation succeeds, do you see it feeding back into fixing the problems with Q&A?

Comment: I see it feeding back into Q&A regardless, @Jeffrey. The successes suggest things we may do without harm; the failures highlight pitfalls to avoid.

Comment: I think the big thing here is that of people posting here and who have been engaged since the beginning, nearly no one _wants_ to see Documentation fail. But when your biggest fans are skeptical of the approach and have lots of valuable input that's being ignored/dismissed, it's really important to actually listen to them. People who read meta are heavily invested in Stack Overflow already and are your biggest fans (and future users/contributors of the product). Alienating _them_ in favor of some silent "user group" or whoever drove the UX and ideas here was the #1 mistake associated with docs

Comment: I *suspect* that's more perception than reality, @enderland ...or rather, as usual there's a tremendous amount of feedback, much of it contradictory, and we're trying to listen to the dulcet 10% amid the cacophony. Not that this makes it any better; if folks don't think they're being heard, that's as bad *for them* as not being heard at all. Something I'd like to see more of here is more regular candid discussion about the *unsolved* problems - not "we know this is a problem", but "we're still conflicted on which direction to go here, because..."

Comment: `you can take a very skilled designer, test the hell out of the resulting design in private, and still end up with something that doesn't really work for the actual target audience`. That kind of means that your designer is not as skilled as you think... Or you dont define skills by achievements? I am still saying that you can get a few things wrong, there are a lot of unknowns. but that is a major fuck-up and everybody should be asking himself how they came to this, with all these amazing people that seem to abound in SO's team.

Comment: The unsolved problems of documentation have been discussed at length over a long period, and it starts with the SO Doc concept itself. People are still confused about what this is about. You insist on a reputation system under the guise that it can be fixed though it seems to be an untractable problem, but you have already discarded a system without rep. You want community-edited content, why? You want Doc and Q&A to be linked together. Why? What does it have to do with the problem? SO has already decided some characteristics to the solution which fit itself, but maybe not the problem.

Comment: @Shog9 What I know _doesn't_ work for gauging effectiveness of edits is to analyze characters added. I know I haven't been contributing to docs since that change (That I could rewrite a topic entirely and make it awesome and still get nothing because I maybe removed more cruft then I added). Not because I'm consumed by hunger for internet points, but because it feels like poor, rambling edits are rewarded and those who actually put in the effort to make things decent aren't.

Comment: Great post. I do violently object to this "fix the failed mission" narrative. Google _anything_ programming related and you'll see that Stack Overflow succeeded wildly. The problem faced is not "what do you do after you fail?" which is really quite easy, but "what do you do after you _succeed_" which is a soul-crushing, vantablack abyss of infinite difficulty.  As for my take on docs, [it is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation/330059#330059) and my mind is unchanged.

Comment: If SO wants the members to not be defensive about new features, the key would be to base them on existing features. If you would have needed a certain rep or badge to post on Documentation or to review Documentation, the quality problem of the content wouldn't have ended up in the sewer. If gold badge users on the specific tag were given rights to freely override or delete posts, you would have gotten topic moderators for free. And so on.

Comment: Part of the problem is that SO is so very afraid of becoming "elitist". But look at traditional encyclopaedias in book form - they are very elitist. They only allow scientists and authorities with vast domain knowledge to write the articles. They wouldn't allow a fresh physics student to write an article about Einstein's theory of relativity and then print hundred thousand books, which are distributed to other students to study from.

Comment: @Lundin: "*If gold badge users on the specific tag were given rights to freely override or delete posts, you would have gotten topic moderators for free.*" We are. Gold badge holders can make any edit they want without external approval. I'm not sure about deletion, but I'm fairly sure we can do that without needing approval either.

Comment: @NicolBolas That wasn't there from the start. I had a gold badge and couldn't delete blatantly incorrect posts. It must have been introduced after I gave up on helping out with Documentation. Which I admittedly did just a few weeks after it was introduced.

Comment: @user3743222 The suggestion that because a lot of people use one service, that you need to be perfectly professional about the next one you roll out is ridiculous. That's exactly what this post is talking about fighting against. I don't mean to get argumentative, but it's like you're pointing at a car crash and were like 'should have driven better'. Those startup ideas are valuable, no reason a massive company couldn't try one on their own.

Comment: @TankorSmash well if you don't mind, and they don't then everything is fine. I mean it is not like we are paying for this - though some of us might spend valuable time who could be used elsewhere - but of course we freely choose to do so. That said, if I buy a smartphone, and the battery burns in flame in my hand, well, I dont know. I wont tell you 'nice try, keep innovating, move fast break things'. And generally speaking, when something fails, you better have a good analysis of what went wrong. That is how you improve. And what I am hearing here, is  we did our best, and fucking up is ok.

Comment: Agreed, paying for a product and having if damage itself or you is bad. Having an optional free product on the side isn't crazy comparable though. Agreed with the rest of your point 100%

Answer (score 74):

I've contributed [a lot to Documentation.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c?tab=documentation&sort=all) Ever since its launch I've wanted it to succeed but the more time I've spent with it, the more it seems to be nothing more than a rep mine.

The only people who seem to be contributing are low-level users who neither understand the material nor seem to be interested in accuracy. Most of my contributions on Docs.SO have been correcting or reverting erroneous additions.

Likewise, I never find myself using it. The search functionality is terrible and there's much better documentation spread across the internet. Combine this with the horrible additions done by low-rep users and it really seems like it's the blind leading the blind.

The **only** thing that has been useful is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) that I point new users to when they ask a question on SO proper and seem to lack essential debugging skills. Maybe that kind of information should have a place on SO.

I can't say for sure if Docs is a failure since I don't have the numbers but I can say that, in my experience, the examples are very poor quality. There's far more users who don't understand the topics trying to contribute then there are source material experts contributing and I don't expect that to ever change. At best, we have a few experts spending time fixing the errors of others rather than contributing original, useful content.

Comment: and a bunch of people upvoting... for who knows what reason

Comment: This is precisely my experience and as a result, I have absolutely no interest in using it.  I don't contribute to it because it feels so overly gamed, I don't use it for my own needs since I am constantly hunting for relevant information due to how the topics are structured and the lack of excellent search capabilities, and I don't want to participate in the review queues since they're largely composed of reviewing bad grammar changes.

Comment: *The search functionality is terrible* Seconded.  I've tried a couple of times to find something and can't.  At least if there some sort of structure to it thing might be easier to find.

Comment: The quality is indeed poor on most things, and the things that are high quality or usually not concise examples as the ideal would have it, but rather comprehensive tutorial style posts, like the one you linked. One of the reasons I've been holding off from contributing myself, is that there are not enough guidelines in place to dictate what is appropriate, or following the guidelines that _are_ there (e.g. no tutorials), would mean getting rid of the most useful things.

Comment: I notice the example you actually found useful has been edited by 26 users with [2 major and 10 minor contributors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/713). Some of those folks have very little in the way of SO reputation. This is exactly the sort of collaborative editing that Documentation was designed to encourage. Would you mind linking some counter-examples of where the system is failing?

Comment: @JonEricson [So](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136668?filter-tags=javascript) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/130337?filter-tags=javascript) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/134382?filter-tags=javascript). [These](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/124798?filter-tags=javascript) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/8873/es2015-variables-deceleration-let#t=20170330133654093) just ones I've cleaned up. It doesn't include the topics which have blown up with minor examples.

Comment: @JonEricson The example I linked to is useful because it has been aggressively moderated by myself and others. If we hadn't been on top of it, it would have quickly fallen apart with misinformation.

Comment: "Can't find myself using it" Same for me. One feature that would really make me use it a lot more is if I could close questions as duplicate "pointers" to a Documentation section. But I've spoken to SO about this already and they seemed receptive, so hopefully that feature will be coming soon.

Answer (score 46):

The docs beta has been up for months and months, and the only time I have ever meaningfully interacted with it was to contribute a few edits to a couple things and wrote out a post on C++ meta-programming, admittedly just to scoop up some reputation while the system was still new and basic topics hadn't been documented yet. I'll take a wild guess that the only people still using it are people who are contributing to topics and rep farming.

Topics are copy-pasted verbatim from elsewhere, with barely a thought given to formatting or context. Obviously it's gotten somewhat better since then, but there's still a giant flaw in the entire idea of the system: it doesn't have any "documentation" that can't be found elsewhere on the internet. In addition, other documentation will likely be better written and more coherently put together since the tone and structure of the examples on Docs.SO is all over the map.

There are so many problems with the service that have already been enumerated elsewhere, and I have no confidence in it's future. My recommendation would be to tuck it away, do a big post mortem, and focus on improving the core SO experience. That, or maybe try some other crazy experimental project, since this one is clearly not going to work.

Answer (score 28):

I found the idea interesting when documentation was announced. I had a particular library in mind when I read the announcement, one that I had used recently and that had a whole bunch of functions that had no documentation apart from their names and types of parameters. I just checked, that library doesn't have any documentation on SO, it's just proposed.

I looked a bit at some other projects I use. But the main issue there is, they already have at least reasonable, and sometimes excellent documentation. There isn't really much need for SO documentation for those.

It is also lacking structure, it's a list of topics sorted by a rather arbitrary popularity measure. Inside each topics are post sorted again by an arbitrary popularity measure. I'm not sure if it's meant to be only used by searching for specific items, but the lack of structure hurts if you just want to browse it.

I looked a bit closer at one documentation topic where the official documentation is pretty excellent. In the SO documentation I found one topic/example that was simply dangerous. The example showed how to backup the database using a specific software. Unfortunately, it didn't explain some important concepts (or anything at all, really), and was missing one half of the process. The backups created this way are actually unusable. And that example is there for more than half a year now.

I still think that creating something that isn't questions and answers, but covers a different angle is a reasonable idea. But I'm not convinced that documentation is the right concept.

Comment: Have you considered suggesting an edit (or simply removing) the dangerous topic?

Comment: @JonEricson It's already deleted. I didn't mention it because I thought it was obvious that I'd try that. I also found another very obvious issue with something that was obviously meant as a comment in the introduction, in a very popular topic. Also removed now, but both were visible for significant timespans. My subjective impression is that there are far fewer eyeballs on this than I'd have guessed.

Comment: Yeah. Many people are doing review of new things (some carefully and [others not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347892/1438)), but not so many people are using Docs yet. It's a bit like those wikis and game guides for niche topics: quality is hit and miss. If one really good writer happens to get interested, you can find some real gems. But, you know, Sturgeon's law. On the plus side, people aren't yet using low-quality topics to screw up their actual projects.

Answer (score 28):

Another question already quoted this SO position:

> Just this week, the executive team gave us a key metric for measuring
>   success in the coming year: user growth.

This is a classical case of [Goodhart's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law). It's the 21st century. Basic company management is not some black witchcraft. We can put the blame for the failure of Documentation right on the shoulders of that executive team.

The only relevant way to judge Docs.SO is to consider the growth in good documentation. There's already enough written in other answers and comments about the details, but that addresses how wide the problem is - not how deep. It appears the problem goes all the way to management.

This management problem is not specific to Docs.SO. The same tension between "high user count" and "site quality" is a problem on the main site as well, and again management is directly involved by declaring what is and is not acceptable.

Comment: TIL Goodhart's Law. While I don't agree with it completely, it brings up a completely valid point. Thanks!

Comment: @Qix despite seeing all days, everyday? Octane was retired for that reason.

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR:  We will be making some big changes in the coming months to address many of the concerns surrounding SO Docs, all towards creating an artifact that is useful to the community at large.**

The details:

Let me start off by saying - Yes, we agree and acknowledge that SO Docs is not a success ***yet*** and has its flaws - both conceptually and implementation wise. There is a reason it is still in ‘beta’.

Now having said that, we at SO, have not given up on it. At its very core, the motivation and reasons for this new undertaking are still very well grounded in an unmet need for our developer community: there simply aren’t enough examples/applications/reusable code samples available for users at different skill levels. No matter how we go about solving it, that problem is very much a reality and still exists.

We truly believe that given the value Q&A offers to the community, example focused documentation can be a very powerful complement to it and provide our users with a richer experience.

But, is our current implementation of Docs, the right way? 
We have come to realize that that in fact is not the case - due largely to all of your input.

We take this feedback and criticism very seriously and have been extremely busy the last few months in better understanding the current perception of Docs and the various problems with the system. We have conducted multiple user research sessions with both users (with varied activity levels) and non users of Docs, all towards unearthing the barriers and motivations to use of the product. Among the issues that surfaced are the very valid concerns around -

1. Structure and Organization - Can all topics be confined to the same, rigid sections? The sorting on the examples and the topics do not feel intuitive/logical.
2. Hierarchy - Is tag-->topic-->example a little too simplistic?
3. Quality concerns - What changes are good and what are not? Eg. Why was a plagiarism related rollback rejected?
4. Navigation - It’s hard to know what SO Docs has (internal search fails) and even harder to navigate topics and the various sections. The browsability isn’t smooth.
5. Context/Completeness - Just examples or code samples without accompanying context or information often makes the former incomplete. And without us having an official way to reference or attribute external material it makes it even harder to do so - resulting in plagiarism and/or inconsistent (but well meaning) ways the community has tried to work around it.

These problems are all very real, and it shows that we have a huge opportunity ahead of us. It also shows that we have our work cut out for us. Like I mentioned earlier, SO is as committed as ever to put our best foot forward with respect to crowdsourced Documentation.

We ask that you keep an open mind and watch out for these updates. We look forward to seeing whether these potentially charter a better path for the product *or not* - and as always, we will be depending on you to share your valuable feedback!

Comment: `there simply aren’t enough examples/applications/reusable code samples available for users at different skill levels. No matter how we go about solving it, that problem is very much a reality and still exists.` SE has *stated* this, but I don't really see any evidence to back up this assertion.  I mean official documentation of most any product tend to not provide this, yes, but I've basically never come across any product, tool, language feature, library, etc. that I couldn't find lots of examples of its use by simply doing a google search on that topic.

Comment: Many of those examples found when searching will be SO questions related to that topic, which is a great way to find example usages of something.  What evidence is there that this is a need not already met?  What about the core SO engine doesn't meet this need?  How does docs meet it any *better* than SO (both in quality of content and in discoverability in this specific situation)?

Comment: It might not be clear, but Vasudha has been working hard behind the scenes to discover the problems with Documentation. I personally appreciate having a completely outside observer dig into the product and root out problems that are obvious to users, but not so clear to those of us who have been working on it for over a year. The user interviews she mentioned have been especially eye-opening since they represent both active Stack Overflow users and people who mostly browse the site. Meanwhile, I've got renewed confidence that the need for something like Documentation exists.

Comment: Somebody needs an employee diamond... :)

Comment: This post also doesn't even mention one of the core problems that Docs has had, and that's its incentive system.  So many of the problems have stemmed from the fact that low quality or actively harmful contributions are highly incentivised, and useful/high quality contributions are not particularly well incentivised.  Structuring the information in a more discoverable way is of course important, but so long as the most effective way to get rep is to just plagiarize other content, that's what people are going to keep doing.

Comment: @Servy: Our interviews with users definitely confirm our hunch. Many users (without our prompting and having no experience with our product) pointed out that official documentation they used day-to-day lacked useful examples. Generally they wanted to see how different features worked together rather than the overly simple examples commonly found. Q&A satisfy some of that need, but not in any systematic way. It's made harder by the fact that "easy" questions tend to get closed (and downvoted and eventually deleted). Documentation has an opportunity to make make space for examples.

Comment: _there simply aren’t enough examples/applications/reusable code samples available for users at different skill levels_ I believe that it is not only about the quantity but it's the quality that matter the most, I think that too much simple or basic examples will achieve the same result - Lack of participation

Comment: @Servy - Issues #3 and #5 in the post, were a way to encapsulate that point. It is fair to bring up the reputation system as a potential cause but it's more because we haven't made the ask clear on what is good and what is not.

Comment: @Servy: Vasudha mentioned reputation in a draft answer I reviewed and I asked her to remove it. Reputation causes strange incentives no matter how it's structured. It helps to consider specific flaws in the incentive system. For plagiarism in particular, a rollback will wipe out any reputation gain a user might have received. So the solution really is to get more eyes on topics to spot the problems and remove them.

Comment: @JonEricson I specifically said that official documentation tends to not have lots of good example, but that they're trivially easy to find by simple searches in existing 3rd party (or even 1st party) resources, such as SO, other Q/A sites, forums, tutorials, blogs, etc.  Adding one more 3rd party source of such examples *when lots already exist* doesn't change the problem of official docs not having them while they're readily available elsewhere.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned how will Docs do better than any existing options out there at providing examples.  As for "easy" questions not being welcome on SO, the "easy" questions that aren't really welcome on SO are questions about topics *where that information is already readily available on the internet*, therefore as a consequence, there clearly isn't a lack of examples of that topic.

Comment: @Servy To be fair, one might reasonably lump the incentive system under "quality concerns", where Vasudha also brings up recognizing what's good and bad. I agree with you about the unclear motivation for Docs, though. My biggest beef with this answer is that it doesn't say "Okay, we get it -- we'll drop the Docs name post-haste, since it's a gross misnomer that side-tracks any and all discussion", but I guess that problem is really tied up in your point about its unclear motivation... Edit: Oof, I'm not seeing "new comment" notifications, so it looks like I'm way behind the convo.

Comment: @Servy: We talked to users of Stack Overflow who _do not contribute_. The do tend to trust example on Q&A if they find them. But when they don't find them, they tend to be at a loss. They certainly don't feel comfortable asking since the question closing rules are largely inscrutable to a non-user. (Try grabbing a co-worker who doesn't use SO and test my assertion.) So if a question exists, SO does a great job. When the question does not exist, readers don't know how to ask productively. (We are working on that problem too, by the way.)

Comment: Practically and going forward, are you considering fixing the situation, or is there also the possibility you'd say "this isn't fixable, let's start over but taking into account what we've learned"?

Comment: @Bart What good will it do (To start over)? What will the community think of the "next big thing" when the last failed attempt was simply thrown out the window

Comment: @AlonEitan, I'm not saying that's a good (nor best) thing to do. I'm wondering what the options are. I'm mostly thinking out loud, considering the "old content" or "content before we got our current standards up" issues we face on SO proper to this day. Documentation could be young enough to say "yeah, that didn't really work, let's start over". But that may indeed not be a realistic option.

Comment: @JonEricson Are you still referring to very intro level concepts in mainstream programming languages, or are you referring to extremely complex and/or niche topics where there simply are no examples to be found on the whole internet?  If you're referring to the former, I've never come across issues like that that don't have readily accessible examples, even if SO isn't one of the top results, if the latter, how does Docs solve the problem any better than SO proper?

Comment: As an aside, the way I'm approaching Docs is in a "community managed tutorial" sort of way. Regardless of existing knowledge on the subject, there should be an entry point into the material in order to advance knowledge. So I've been trying to create some starter examples on the [Minecraft] docs area because I know there are a few problem spots new creators face and having a known-current resource is essential. On the Forge forums people have to be told daily "don't do X, it is bad" and the reason they do X is because of an old tutorial from someone who wasn't that skilled to begin with.

Comment: @Servy: I'm talking about the latter. Docs does not solve that problem (or, to be honest, any problem at all) at the moment. Vasudha is guiding us toward a few things we are going to try in the next few months. It's still beta and community driven products just take a lot more iterations to get right than other sorts of software.

Comment: @JonEricson: "*I'm talking about the latter.*" Then step 1 needs to be *changing the name*. "Documentation" is not for "extremely complex and/or niche topics". One of the big problems with Docs.SO is that you keep using words against their well established meanings. If you're going to have some major restructuring of Docs.SO, so that it serves "extremely complex and/or niche topics" effectively, then it *must* use the right terminology from Day 1. And "Documentation" isn't it.

Comment: @Jon Good to hear that y'all are open to iterating further, since your Dec update referred to "the software skeleton nearing completion" while the consensus view among meta folks seems to be that it doesn't work well enough yet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339974/

Comment: So what happens to all the low quality, poorly organized, unnecessary content that gets in while you guys work this out? I'd really like to see a full reset (with a data dump so that we can re-add the real gems) once making this useful is finally nailed down.

Comment: I feel like until SO as a whole understands why there is such frustration with docs this "it's not a success __yet__" approach is just going to make people more annoyed with the whole thing. Your list of 5 criticisms has been articulated ad nauseum for about 1 hour longer than Docs has been in public beta. It's sad to me it took over a year for this to be realized and acknowledged by Stack Overflow as a whole. It doesn't give me confidence in the future of Docs going forward if it takes a year for _obvious_ issues to be recognized officially as legitimate.

Comment: @enderland: "*Your list of 5 criticisms has been articulated ad nauseum for about 1 hour longer than Docs has been in public beta.*" Correction: some of those were well articulated *before* public beta. But your overall point is valid; it shouldn't require this much effort to convince the Powers That Be of the reality of Docs.SO. And it is very disconcerting that they had to take surveys of users before they could finally accept what they're users here were telling them.

Comment: @enderland: I think you might be confusing (hopeless?) optimism for dismissal of your collective concerns. We knew some these items might be problems during private beta, but figured we'd be able to solve them. It sounds like you hoped we'd throw in the towel before even trying. (But maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment?) It's also weird to leave that comment now.  Who cares how long it takes to for "issues to be recognized officially"? We finally have a full time PM and "officially" recognized them _now_.

Comment: @JonEricson So you anticipated a bunch of problems, and also recognized them early, but...choose not to do anything about them and just left the problematic features as they were.  That's...not exactly inspiring optimism.  Why should we *now* give you the benefit of the doubt and trust that you're going to actually make relevant improvements that will actually fix the underlying problems?  Sure, acknowledging the problem is good, and I'm glad SE is finally doing that, but you have a ways to go to actually earn the trust of your user base back.

Comment: @JonEricson sometimes the most optimistic thing to do is quit when you're ahead. I guess, that ship sailed months (years?) ago for Documentation. Now, it's at an even worse spot - do you wipe _everything_ out when you eventually revamp it (thus alienating the only people currently even interested in it)? Or do you just accept Docs will have massive tech debt in terms of low quality documentation and just hope for something miraculous to occur where all the users you've spent a _year_ or more frustrating magically come in and save the day?

Comment: @enderland: I feel like folks misunderstand how collaborative software gets built. It doesn't come fully formed out of the mind of the developers. (Developers aren't [Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanence#Ancient_Greek_philosophy).) Instead, we try some things, see how people use them, fix problems, and iterate. In hindsight, it's obvious we haven't fixed the most pressing things, but that doesn't mean we can't start now. (But maybe you mean we should never have tried in the first place? I really can't tell.)

Comment: Why did the flagship feature that grabbed a large portion of developer attention over the past year and majorly affected the dynamics of the site only just now get a project manager?

Comment: @JonEricson: "*I feel like folks misunderstand how collaborative software gets built.*" But if you look at successful collaborative platforms, more often than not what you find is that version 1.0 got a lot more right than wrong. MediaWiki is much more rich today than it was before, but the general idea of its initial release has been preserved. SO today has a lot of stuff in place that it didn't have originally, but the basic concept of Q&A remains. Docs.SO doesn't have that; whatever changes you're looking at making, if they're going to work at all, will have to be fundamental.

Comment: "*maybe you mean we should never have tried in the first place*" I think his point (and if not his, then mine) is that, if someone tells you that you're about to drive off a cliff, and you respond with, "don't worry, we'll spontaneously grow wings", it's disconcerting to see you drive off that cliff (for the better part of a year) before you manage to find someone who convinces you that people cannot spontaneously grow wings. From our perspective, the failure of Docs.SO as designed was predictable and obviously so. So we're concerned that it took so long to convince you of that.

Comment: @davidism: To be fair, the team had a product manager but he was also doing double duty as the technical lead while also managing another team. SO realized that they needed a dedicated product person to help identify the future for Docs (if there is indeed one) and allow for it to get a fair shot at achieving it's intended purpose and potential. We clearly aren't done trying.

Comment: @NicolBolas it... sort of reminds me way too much of this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg - "The Expert"

Comment: `the motivation and reasons for this new undertaking are still very well grounded in an unmet need for our developer community: [...] not enough examples/applications/reusable code samples available for users at different skill levels. [...] that problem is very much a reality and still exists`. That is the assumption that you should first start to challenge and measure. How many active users are on SO? Make a survey. Do they need what you describe? Do they describe their doc need the same way you do? Take the non-active users, and do the same. My point is you can measure instead of asserting.

Comment: @enderland That video is--no joke--literally my last permanent job.  It eventually got to the point at which I stood up and said, "I don't have to take this" and walked out in the middle of a project.

Comment: @user3743222: "*My point is you can measure instead of asserting.*" How do you measure a population when many of them are not actually users of your site yet?

Comment: ? there are like, a thousand ways. That is every day marketing/consumer research.

Comment: The minimal viable product would have been to use an off-the-shelf wiki and manually enforce your desired structure during the private beta, and only then build the tooling as necessary to support what your users actually did.  That would have been more consistent with the "UC Irvine design philosophy" you espouse, and would have shown you right away if experts were interested in contributing in this format.

Comment: The issue here is the feedback loop. You go way too far into building out a product, put it out there, gather feedback (post after post like this) and presumably hold private meeting for months on end trying to figure things out. With a big new idea, get small things out quickly, and b ready, willing and able to change quickly given feedback and data. This is the big failure and it hurts the brand when post after post like this comes out and no one can see that anything is being done, just vague hints at 'something'. By the time you're ready to do something, it's now too late for many reasons.

Comment: I honestly fail to see what Documentation is supposed to provide above and beyond SO. If you want to know how to perform a certain task using a given technology, you search Stack Overflow. If there isn't a question about it yet, you ask one. _Stack Overflow is example based documentation_. Docs.SO is just... sad.

Answer (score 18):

To decide whether it is a failed experiment, you need metrics. And those metrics have been exposed here (quoting from [The dawn of Documentation: a solstice update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339974/the-dawn-of-documentation-a-solstice-update/339987#339987)):

> Just this week, the executive team gave us a key metric for measuring
>   success in the coming year: user growth.

It is pretty clear that whatever features SO Docs have, or resists keeping, is a result of the criteria imposed by the decision makers who drive the company.

Those decision makers' interests is supposed to go hand in hand with the interests of the community :

> Obviously there’s a business reason for that goal, but it
>   serendipitously benefits the quality of Documentation as well. As Eric
>   Raymond notes, “Given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow.”
>   Similarly, the more people who use Documentation to understand their
>   code, learn a new feature or even answer questions on Stack Overflow,
>   the more reliable the content will become.

You will find there some reasons behind why it is sought to maximize the number of contributors and their incentive to contribute (generate user growth through : attracting new users to the platform ; lowering the bar for existing users to create content, which also attract new users by network effect). This is supposed to be good for the community as more users is, according to the quote, linked to better quality.

What I think we have learnt for now is that volume of users (whether contributing users or just end users) does not really correlate with the quality of the documentation. Some might even argue the opposite. About the user growth side of the equation, I can't tell (nor do I care, though I understand they have to monetize their work (and ours) one way or another).

I think we should just stop caring. We don't own the company, they have all legitimacy to pursue any project they see fit, any way that they see fit. If we don't like a particular project, we should just focus on what we like and let them care about their own. And be grateful for the things that we indeed find useful.

Comment: I agree that they're allowed to work on what they want, but I observe that most of the frustration is that they appear to be pouring so much effort into docs to the neglect of all the other long standing requests about their existing products. You know, all the stuff we like and care about.

Comment: This is a typical case where the interests of the company diverge from the interests of the community. They have to generate significant future cash flows for their investors (and themselves) while avoiding alienating a community who contributes freely (in both senses of the term) to their success. So the community certainly has some influential power but it doe not drive the company. Rather than entertaining or assuming some philanthropic motivation, we should be thinking about what exactly we are getting from SO and contributing, and adjust our time investment accordingly. No free lunch!

Comment: @user3743222 sure, but where do the free laborers come from that actually give Stack Overflow as a company business value? The community. It's a symbiotic relationship. Both us as users and SO as a company need to see the relationship as symbiotic.

Comment: Of course, and I think they very much do so. It just so happens that they have problems finding growth avenues which are in line with the community (actual/stated/fantasized) needs. I will always remember how the 25-year-old Zuckerberg flat out declared that people no longer had an expectation of privacy and consequently changed the privacy settings of its then 350MM users. This obviously had to do with the fact that they made a profit from people's information. Anyways, turns out the assumption was wrong and they updated their tune. I do believe SO will update its tune too, eventually.

Comment: It seems StackOverflow forgot why they beat ExpertsExchange - the focus on quality over quantity. The quantity of users that came to StackOverflow was a consequence of quality. Putting quantity first indeed does not work.

Answer (score 16):

Docs is a double nested XY problem.

First, it's a solution which we are all discussing to the root problem of "what should Stack Overflow as a company do next?" The underlying problem that spawned Docs is *that* question, not "is Docs a good idea?" -- whether Docs is a good idea doesn't actually matter because it's *not the underlying question needing to be addressed*.

Second, the reason Docs has so much pushback is that even assuming it is a good idea, the "case" for Docs hasn't been made and agreed upon. It's been presented as a solution to some "handwavy problem" but the root problem it supposedly solves isn't one which people really completely agree upon and so all the discussion is around the solution and not the actual problem.

If Docs had started with involved meta discussion around, "what are the main issues people face when finding documentation or examples online?" I think it would have had considerably more success. Because it would have ultimately been developed to solve a **real** problem people are facing and the solution itself would have been tuned to actually address a felt problem.

Comment: Upvoted for catchy-ness of first sentence. I thought it failed because there wasn't a high enough barrier to contribution.  I often came across poorly written sections in my domain of expertise put there by people prolific doc contributors with minimal SO rep. I might edit, but it often took more time than if I had just written a section. And it was a lot harder than answering an SO question.

Answer (score 11):

When this launched I posted [Will Documentation duplicate effort and waste resources?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328802/308851) but my fears became naught: instead of sucking away the already scarce documentation efforts it became a wasteland. It looks like an MVP that a summer intern typed some examples into, some of it right, some of it wrong, shallow and useless. If Shog9 is right and it's about experimenting, well, the experiment ran its course and it's pretty much dead.

You need to ask the why.

Why do we answer on StackOverflow? There's the "pay it forward" mechanism: today it's me who shares his knowledge, tomorrow it'll be you.  Also, often I do it for myself -- I figure out some obscure stuff that I do not need every day so I won't memorize but I might need it later and so I need to put it somewhere and where better than SO? Even if I write both halves of the Q-A pair, commenters will force me to make it better. If I write an answer, I do not need to write the question but still I need to provide a legible answer. A month or two later, or even a few years later as I search for the info, I find my own. Awesome. Anyways, we have clear goals: an understandable question, an understandable, to the point answer and a well oiled machinery to refine it all.

In documentation -- basic information can be found elsewhere and complex information is simply a much better fit for Q&A. I can't find a reason to write docs here as it is not the official docs. I can find a reason to refine the official docs for sure -- we want better docs. But creating new, parallel comprehensive docs from ground up? Ain't nobody got time for that. Documentation lacks motivation, goals and refinery mechanism all of which has been ingeniously provided by the existing Q&A site. The lack of motivation is a big problem for primary docs, double, triple so for secondary like this.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm in the minority here, but I still believe the essential idea behind Docs.SO is a good one. I'm relatively new to programming, and I very often find myself reading official documentation and wishing it had more code examples. "Show, don't tell" is an important principle from storytelling that also applies to documentation; even a very good explanation of what a function does is incomplete without an example showing the code in place, working. Official documentation often lacks this. More than once I have given up on a library altogether because the documentation didn't meet my needs; now I make a habit of valuing helpful docs over fast performance or good features.

Documentation.SO's current usefulness is limited by poor searchability. I understand that the site's content isn't yet considered good enough to include in Google search, but the current workflow of

1. visit StackOverflow.com
2. click "Documentation"
3. search for a tag
4. click the tag
5. search inside the tag

is a bit painful. Having a single place where we could search all of Docs.SO would help a lot; you could then filter the results on the other end to the tags you're interested in, [much like MDN does with their "Topics" filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=).

I recognize and respect the frustration of my fellow StackExchange users. I've only really programmed in HTML/CSS/JavaScript with a bit of Ruby; I've heard that other areas of the site are disasters, and I hope that stuff will be fixed. But Docs.SO *has* created some useful pages; the one on [Debugging JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging#t=201704192021104391733) taught me a lot, and this [guide to HTML's `<input>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/277/input-control-elements#t=20170419202935391755) is better and more continually useful than anything I've found anywhere else.

It feels like Docs.SO isn't useful to everyone, and in particular it seems to be not-useful to veterans of StackOverflow. That's a problem. I hope StackOverflow can fix it. But it is useful to me, and I'd be sad to see it discarded.

Comment: So if you're looking for some example usage of some function, and don't see such an example in the official docs, do you actually fail to find *any* examples using it when you do a web search on that function?  If you're searching on commonly used items like, HTML's "input" tag, then that's going to be a "no".  So Docs is attempting to solve a problem *that Google has already solved*.  (And it's doing it, as you yourself noted, in a much worse and less usable manor.)

Comment: "Any examples"? No. But the examples I find usually aren't clear because they're oriented toward some other purpose. Docs.SO is a great place to find minimal, complete, verifiable examples.

Comment: Also, of course there are lots of examples for HTML's `<input>`--that's about as mainstream as you get. Finding examples of things that are more narrowly used is more difficult. I pointed out the `<input>` page because of the quality of its examples; it's comprehensive but not excessively verbose.

Comment: Ostensibly, Docs is supposed to providing real world example of actual usages of the things that they're providing examples of, not just toy snippets.  This is precisely because seeing the toy snippet that doesn't do anything productive is usually what you *do* see out of official documentation.  And of course even doing a simple search you're still likely to find reasonably minimal complete examples rather easily, so long as you're not looking into extremely niche topics.  It's also worth pointing out that right now Docs *isn't* a good place to find such examples, it just *wants* to be.

Comment: And those extremely niche topics are precisely the things that you're *not* going to find good examples of on Docs either.  Docs is attempting to solve the problem for the cases that Google already solves well (widely used, simple, mainstream topics), and isn't really working to try to solve the problem in the cases where it doesn't (extremely niche topics that see very little use).

Comment: There's a lot of documentation out there that should provide snippets, but doesn't. That's what Docs.SO is for. There's also many libraries that are poorly documented; Docs.SO provides a place where users can document that stuff if they want.

You're quite correct that Docs isn't serving many of these cases well. I agree. But I think Docs can grow to serve these cases. I want to see that happen. 

Docs.SO is trying to fulfill a need that I feel acutely. It's far from perfect, but it's better than what we had before.

Comment: Part of what makes Docs weird is that it's intended as something that fits into gaps, like caulk into a crack. So when you look at Docs, it's like a partial map of all the places on the Internet where documentation is bad, not like a standalone edifice.

Comment: No, it's not better than what you had before.  It's not even better than other options *that you have now*.  You acting as if there is official documentation, Docs.SO, and nothing else.  That's just not true.  There's a whole internet out there full of examples.  Everything Docs has documented and *lots* more already has lots of readily accessible snippets that are as good or better than what Docs has, and Docs doesn't solve that problem any better than other sources (in fact, it's *worse*).  So the problem Docs solves isn't a problem, and the actual problems out there aren't solved by Docs.

Comment: But Docs *isn't* filling the gaps.  It's just providing lower quality versions of what's already accessible, and *not* providing information not already out there.  It's literally acting as the exact *opposite* of that.

Comment: Where do you look for examples? Usually on Google I find official docs, SO Q&A, and forum examples where people post broken code and fail to get help.

Comment: Name a mainstream or other widely used function/operation/etc. for which you can't find working example usages in the first page of Google.  Or better still, one where the only working example is Docs.

Comment: It's true that Docs doesn't provide much coverage for rarely-used libraries. I wish it would. It does a good job on some of the popular stuff. The HTML `<input>` entry linked above is, to my eye, more complete, more navigable, and has better examples than the corresponding MDN entry. I want to see that expanded to less popular stuff, and I'm willing to help work on it.

Comment: @Servy: Is your argument that SO Documentation is so terrible it will break Google? At the moment, Docs isn't working because _nobody can find anything_. If it ever _does_ show up in a Google search, SO Docs has one advantage that most other search results don't have: anyone can edit the page. (Though that isn't really an advantage over MDN, I suppose.)

Comment: @DawnPaladin: "*I know I'm in the minority here, but I still believe the essential idea behind Docs.SO is a good one.*" OK, I'll play; what *is* the "essential idea behind Docs.SO"? Because if you ask 5 people that question, you'll get 5 different answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's right there in the answer: "I very often find myself reading official documentation and wishing it had more code examples." That's also point #2 of the [original pitch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow): "Often documentation is lacking in examples, or the examples are trivial and don't demonstrate typical use." Add me ("community-driven, example-first documentation") and you got 3 of 5, which isn't bad.

Comment: @JonEricson I'll buy the first two, though I think it only makes 1, and that is not a bad thing. But why community-driven? why example-first? This comes already expressed as a solution, not as a problem. The question again and again is what is the problem. How much of a problem is it? What you express really seems like forcing existing SO technology into another domain independently of how much it fits the problem space. If there was no SO, and your problem was to add more/better/more realistic code examples, how would you go about it? And would you call it Code Examples or Documentation?

Comment: I upvote the answer because it addresses helpfully the question, and shows at least one person finds it useful. Though the examples given (debugging, and inputs) are all content that can be found elsewhere, whether in more simplified or detailed form - in any case they do not constitute an example of domain where documentation is lacking in examples - long or short. There might be an advantage for some users, specially beginners in having it in one place (topic). This brings the interesting question of how much value is created by structuring existing content rather than creating new content.

Comment: @user3743222: Eh. ["The perfect is the enemy of the good."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Voltaire) We've got some obvious things to do to improve the current product, which just might become good enough. We aren't starting from first principles here. The Stack Exchange community is already darn good at generating useful content and as a company we are already in the business of supporting that sort of activity.

Comment: @JonEricson No, my argument is not that Docs will break Google.  My argument is that Docs is trying to solve a problem *that Google has already solved*.  Trying to provide example usages to people *when they can already trivially find as many example usages as they want* isn't adding value to the internet.  As for them not being able to edit; a large portion of the sites that are going to show up *will* have a way for that person to add more information to the page.

Answer (score -2):

No. Unequivocally no.

It was a successful experiment. Successful because the experiment tested/trialled something called [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), whose stated goal was:

> "Documentation was our attempt at improving existing reference
>   materials by focusing on examples"

The **result** of that successful experiment was to find that, as one can read in the other answers, SO Documentation, as implemented and run in the experiment, was unpopular and unsuccessful in achieving stated goal, failing to reach a number of hoped-for objectives in a number of metrics.

I argue that the experiment would have been unsuccessful if it had not been able to reach a conclusion about the utility of the SO Documentation project as it was implemented. 
In addition, based on [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) it appears that the SO team has learned things it did not know before, complete with data to back that knowledge (see bottom of [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348030/is-documentation-a-failed-experiment/348143#348143)). The distinction between suspected/expected/assumed/thought/rumoured/stated, and **known** is subtle at times, but very real. It appears that a lot of users expected this trial to be unsuccessful, but it took a **successful** experiment to reach that conclusion for certain.

Comment: In the vernacular sense that I asked the question, the answer is "yes". It was an experiment that failed to yield a successful product. In the scientific sense, where any experiment from which something is learned is "successful", we **hope** it was a success.